# Should we edit obvious spam?

Tags: discussion, edits, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with Spam-Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52475/how-to-deal-with-spam-users)

I recently saw [this spam answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365489/questions-every-good-net-developer-should-be-able-to-answer/3071283#3071283) which I edited to remove the content and link. Is this what we should do? Or should we just flag as spam and leave it alone?

Comment: It could potentially have an impact on the site's SEO performance (if it keeps happening). I'd say, the best thing to do is to edit it as soon as possible, or mark it as spam, then delete it.

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't edit it.

The difference is that flagging for spam is a democratic process while editing is not. Obvious spam is going to get removed quickly anyway.

If you edit the spam posts, other people first have to digg into the history before flagging as spam.

*However, there's one case in which you should edit:* If the answer provides valuable information you should remove the spam part, because otherwise the good part gets deleted too. I doubt there many such posts.

Comment: Editing out the link or name of a product before Google comes on the post is something I do, and which should be done, in my opinion. Editing is very easy to rollback, in case of a mistake, especially that it places the question on top of recent activity. However, it should remain indeed visible that this is a spam, taking away the whole text is not ideal.

Comment: @Gnoupi: All external links have the [rel=nofollow attribute](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2005/01/preventing-comment-spam.html). There's no need to remove those links.

Comment: I asked for more details on your similar comment, on the [other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52475/how-to-deal-with-spam-users/52476#52476).

Answer (score -1):

If it's long and annoying, I'll edit it out besides flagging as spam.

Why?

Because I can see deleted posts, so deleted long and annoying spam posts are still long and annoying. And if I hold off until it's spam-deleted, it gets locked.

Comment: This bothers me too, so if you flag these I don't mind deleting the text from them.

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem anymore, deleted answers get sorted last.

Comment: @Georg: Not *as much* of a problem, yes, that's true.