# Spambot user milind & process around notifying moderators

Tags: support, stack-overflow, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with Spam-Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52475/how-to-deal-with-spam-users)

https://stackoverflow.com/users/354950/milind

I've flagged its posts and removed them as they come up. Just wondering if there is anyway to flag a user as a known/suspected spambot for moderator attention?

Is there something we should do or just let it run its course and it will get sorted when it gets sorted?

Comment: Looks like a mod took care of this user.

Answer (score 0):

Flagging for mod attention should be sufficient; if it's something urgent (or urgently bad) it's OK to mail the address linked at the bottom of every page, too!