# Where's the line between Helpful, Advertisment and Spam?

Tags: discussion, advertising, spam

I've just dig up [this user](https://superuser.com/users/42364/monica-sharma) on SU, which seems like a Spam-User against a website for document converting. The website however is free to use (registration needed, though) and might even be helpful in some of the answered questions.

My first thought was to flag and edit everything I find of that user, like said in [a previous question of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52475/how-to-deal-with-spam-users), but this seems to me like it is a bordercase...the mentioned website seems free to use, so it doesn't fall into the 'normal' Spam-Category...however, it sure floods SU with it, but on the other hand the link might be helpful to some people.

Your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey! Can't a beautiful blonde young woman holding a huge buttercup run her own [online document conversion service](http://onlinedocumentconversion.com) without getting harassed anymore? That is chauvinistic oppression, that is. I think that's a great site on [online document conversion](http://onlinedocumentconversion.com). In fact, the world of [online document conversion](http://onlinedocumentconversion.com) would be poorer without it.

Comment: In seriousness though, while "she" is technically doing it right - showing her affiliation in "her" profile - this has more than crossed the border to spamminess to me. Flaggine her posts right now.

Comment: You're right...the answer is obvious. Now if you'll excuse...I have some flagging to do. ;)

Comment: dangit, DELETED :(

Comment: @drachenstern sadly, I didn't keep a picture.

Comment: I understand. Shame tho ;)