# Limits for self-promotion in answers

Tags: support, faq, answers, etiquette, spam

It's [been](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15432/is-posting-links-to-your-own-blog-site-valid) [covered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29954/on-topic-self-promotion) [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15787/how-do-i-mention-my-own-products-in-answers) that posting links to your own website is ok, but should there be a line drawn? There were several spam flags today for [Ira Baxter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120163/ira-baxter)'s recent posts, presumably because they all link to his website. Initially I disagreed because his answers seem for the most part relevant to the question, but then I looked into it more and realized there's three things that set this apart from most of the related cases that have come up:

- This isn't an occasional thing -- he's posted [412 links to his website](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22semanticdesigns.com%22%20user:120163&tab=newest) in the last year
- This isn't a random blog he writes for a fun, it's a for-profit company he [founded](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Company/People/idbaxter/index.html) and makes money promoting
- I'm not willing to go through all 412, but from the sample I checked, he generally doesn't mention that the products he's recommending are his own. The site is linked from his profile, but most people aren't going to check that

Is all this considered acceptable use, or are the spam flags accurate?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Comment: Would it change anything if Ira disclosed how many sales he's made from links in his SO posts (if he even has such information)?  Fewer sales would imply spammier posts, while more sales would imply useful posts.  And of course, I ask this rhetorically... I don't really expect Ira to just hand out the details about his company.

Comment: @Mark: Yes, those details are unlikely to appear here.   I suggest you simply examine how many of my answers are upvoted.

Comment: It might be worth noting those 412 links point to something like 20 different pages, each one a different tool for a specific problem. And a fair fraction get upvotes, indicating somebody thought the answer was reasonable.  So I might look odd because I probably act like 20 different tool sources, all rolled under one name.  And that might explain why I can provide a lot of answers to a broad audience.

Comment: "he's posted 412 links to his website in the last year" — I thought SO was about the question and answer, not the user. In that case, why is the relative rate of product related answers relevant? To put it another way: if that had been 412 genuinely different users posting those same answers, would you have a problem? If not, why not? Wouldn't it be exactly the same information?

Comment: I've asked a *similar* question some time ago, maybe it does help: [Where's the line between Helpful, Advertisment and Spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56383/wheres-the-line-between-helpful-advertisment-and-spam)

Comment: Folks, as a general reminder, no matter what the outcome of the discussion,. let's be civil here, okay? The person in question has never hidden his identity, and is going out of his way to participate in the discussion here, and to comply with whatever solution the community is working out. Please when participating here, let's bring our cool heads only and leave everything else at the door.

Comment: @defty: The information tends to be more biased and less objective/reliable if the posts are by the guy that is selling the tools getting recommended. @all: Here are [67 additional posts with links](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q="semdesigns.com"%20user%3a120163).

Comment: FWIW, this discussion directly inspired the current policy for promotion found under /help/behavior and /help/promotion *on every site*. Although it was triggered by a discussion on Stack Overflow, the outcome reaches much further and the discussion remains an important artifact for those interested in understanding this policy. Thus, it will not be moved.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who participated in this discussion, particularly Ira.

Based on what we've decided in this question, I have updated the /faq on all sites to make it policy:

> #### May I promote products I am affiliated with here?
>
> The community generally frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam, so be careful. Post good, relevant answers, and if they happen to be about your product, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation with the product in your answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product, you're clearly here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; [contact our ad sales team](https://stackoverflow.com/about/contact) for details. We also offer [free vote-based advertising for open source projects](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source-advertising).

(Note: This guidance has since moved to the Help Center pages [Expected Behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) and [How to not be a spammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).)

---

See also:

- "[Defining the limits of self-promotion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86717/282094)"
- "[How do I mention my own products in answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15787/282094)"
- "[How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94022/282094)"
- "[Encyclopedia Stack Exchange vs. commercial products](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133526/282094)"
  for further discussion about: frequently linking, supporting commercial products by seeking out questions to answer, and where the ***line*** is between "fair and useful" as opposed to simply trying to obtain free promotion for free or commercial products.

Comment: If enterprising individuals with an ad budget would like officially sanctioned plugs (ads on the right, say) to their commercial products to show on specific questions (as Ira has shown by his quantity of answers) isn't this a revenue and development opportunity for SO/SE sites? Targeted, narrowly placed ads placed by carefully by the advertiser.... or is this getting into "roll your own AdWords scale endeavor? (Or would it end being too much work relative to its potential for abuse? or is this basically what SO ads strive to do?)

Comment: @jared contact ads@stackoverflow.com -- our rates are very reasonable!

Comment: I only now discovered that this guy is here now, too. I remember him annoying the hell out of me in Usenet a decade or two ago with posting "answers" solely to plug his company's products. I am appalled the guy is still around, and I am appalled he hadn't been caught out at SO yet.

Comment: Jeff, There is one user who has been constantly been promoting you tube videos in-spite being warned by several experts. What should be our stand in this? Flag his latest post (which has already been edited)?

Comment: @siddharth always flag!

Answer (score 59):

**Policy suggestion**

If an official policy is going to be set on this, I would suggest it say that whenever

- somebody mentions a product they are affiliated with - *commercial or otherwise*
- or makes factual statements about it ("It can do X but does take Y into consideration"; "It runs well on a XYZ series server")
- Simply any kind of answer that would directly influence a purchase/usage decision

they make their affiliation reasonably clear **inside the answer**.

To avoid every answer from a software company employee being loaded with a huge footer of mumbo-jumbo, I suggest that using the word "our" or "my" be enough to indicate the affiliation:

> **I am looking for an extremely fast solution to swarble gorgles in a multi-server environment. Any recommendations?**
>
> Our Quadruptron IV can do this. It can swarble 50 gorgles per second.

Alternatively, they can of course also use a normal disclaimer at the end of the contribution ("Full disclosure: I am CEO of Quadruptron, Inc.") or "I am the maintainer of the project" or whatever. The affiliation is very easy to work into the text flow.

Normal questions involving a product should **not** require full disclosure in the question text, although I would say it mostly makes sense for everyone involved and is good style.

**It goes without saying that an answer needs to be a valuable contribution in the context of the question asked in any case.**

---

I think that the presence of software vendors - commercial and otherwise - on SO in general is a **great thing**, especially because it's in their own best interest to answer questions about their product when/if they come up.

Comment: OK by me... you might need to allow "our" or "my" depending on the size of the poster.

Comment: Good. But you can elaborate why the 2nd bullet, or the "which product Z does not" are important? And as for the question: would there be some limit for how often one can refer to one's own things?

Comment: @Arjan I think full disclosure is important in feature comparisons because on SO, they often involve statements like "It can do x, y and z, but in my experience, performance is awful and z is supported *in theory*, but in practice it never works because..." these are things a software vendor would not say about their own product or have different views on it (which is perfectly fine). I want to know whether a 100% positive judgement comes from an unbiased source who has used the product, or from the vendor.

Comment: @Arjan there should be no limit IMO as long as the rules are followed. (That an answer needs to be a valuable contribution in the context of the question *in any case* goes without saying.)

Comment: But then [the following](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224752/how-to-navigate-around-and-get-familiar-with-large-c-or-c-code-base/3224863#3224863) would not be subject to full disclosure? *The SD Test Coverage family of test coverage tools can accomplish these tasks, computing coverage, coverage unions, coverage differences, and unions of coverages across langauges. The display shows browsable source text with code that is covered or not. These tools have been tested on software systems with millions of lines of code, and are available for C, C++, Java, C#, COBOL and PLSQL.*

Comment: @Arjan yup, it absolutely would: It is clearly a product recommendation (in that somebody is asking for a tool to do x with) and statement about features.

Comment: Okay, so maybe the part "which product Z does not" in the 2nd bullet should be removed from the example?

Comment: @Arjan good point, done.

Comment: Many answers suggest commercial products, provided by people unrelated to the product. (Hunt for any mention of "NCover"). Merely listing its existence with the implication that it is useful influences the decision to "buy" for some definition of "buy". I think you list might be very short: "if they mention a product with which they are affiliated."

Comment: @Ira true. I changed the wording to "mentions" which made the 3rd bullet superfluous. I think the 2nd bullet should stay in case somebody else brings the product up asking for a factual statement ("Is xyz 64-bit compatible?")

Comment: Suddenly realizing that 412 out of 670 answers is more than 60%, I think some limit would be in place. (I've updated my answer, @Ira & Pekka.)

Comment: @Arjan hmmm.... You have a point. It's not a problem if ten people do it, but it would become one if everyone did. However, I would tend to postpone any limiting until the need really comes up.

Comment: @Ira, as for your *Many answers suggest commercial products, provided by people unrelated to the product. (Hunt for any mention of "NCover")* Very true, 585 results by many different people [for NCover](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22NCover%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com), but ALL of the 10 results for "SD Test Coverage" [are yours](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22SD+Test+Coverage%22+site:stackoverflow.com). (Please note I really don't mean to make this personal, but I don't have other examples.)

Comment: I think mentions of competing products also need to be explicitly called out.

Comment: @Arjan: And those cover Java, C#, C, C++, and PHP. That's an average of *2* per language. *Those are separate products* and serve seperate subgroups of SO users which work in different langauges. What I do may look odd to Stack Overflow, because we build dozens of tools. Most tool vendors, especially small companies, have 1 or two tools. Remember that discussion earlier about career-changing events? Consequence: we have lots of useful answers.

Comment: @Pekka: "...would become one if everyone did..." Would it, if each response provides a different answer that reasonably addresses the OP's question? I personally find the oft-recurring redundancy (same product/tool recommendation) among the multiple answers more problematic; it just raises the volume of text to read.

Comment: I don't like policies for every nonsense, but I can understand, that Ira needs some kind of "legal certainty". So let's go with this.

Comment: Pekka, I think your heart is in the right place, but... This should not be necessary. You're effectively setting up guidelines for targeted advertising on SO - and there's already a system in place for that. One or two self-promoting answers out of 100 might be called a misunderstanding; 400+ is a blatant attempt to get around paying for your ads, and deserves neither sympathy nor "clarification".

Comment: @Ira, as for your *That's an average of 2 per language* -- no matter if you categorize by language, those are still ALL yours. I thought your point in your example was that many others promote products they are *unrelated* to, which is indeed true. My search shows that despite the upvotes, nobody except you promotes that specific product your company makes. (Other examples could prove me wrong. Do you have any other examples?)

Comment: @Shog9 Re Ira, I must say that I've never felt irritated by his answers because his product recommendations always actually answer the question asked. I have asked questions which Ira answered and while I never ended up choosing his product, I felt the contribution was reasonable and I didn't really care whether it's the vendor who links to it or not. This is why I tend to defend him here. If it is decided that promoting your own products to this extent is not okay at all, I can totally live with that as well.

Comment: @Shog9 Re the guideline suggestion, what goes without saying is that the self-promoting answer must still be a relevant contribution to the asker's question. So I don't think it can really be called a guideline for targeted advertising, it would just be putting into a rule something for which there already is a Meta opinion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15787?tab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @Shog9: Is this kind of activity really circumventing the ad system? A vendor can either pay for advertising by giving SO money, at which point they can just forget about it, or they can have an employee post useful answers that promote their product. As long as the answers are in fact useful, they are still contributing to the community, just using time instead of money.

Comment: own questions, and they never felt out of place to me, even though I never chose the product. Example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654533/intelligent-file-search-for-windows-that-can-ignore-whitespace-and-search-in-code it doesn't mean I'm agreeing with every one of his 600 answers; I'm just saying I do not have the impression he is a malicious spammer, especially not with the effort he is showing here to work out a solution.

Comment: @Pekka: I didn't think you were, but wanted to make sure. There are a fairly wide variety of questions covered in the list posted by Michael here, and we may simply be focusing on different types: I'm far more concerned about answers to questions that *aren't* requesting tools - disclosure or not, I'm very uncomfortable with systematic link-answering of questions on, say, strategy or technique.

Comment: @Shog9: I don't believe that promotional links should be overlooked if they are gratuitous. But if a valid answer to "how do I do x" is "use product y," I don't think that it should be penalized just because the person writing the answer has a personal stake; I would rather leave that to the community moderation system. That said, I've presented the solution I feel is most appropriate as [a separate answer.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limit-to-self-promotion-in-answers/57625#57625)

Comment: @Shog9 questions in which no product recommendations were requested are indeed a grey area. While I think John Saunders is being too harsh with the example he points to, I would not necessarily be opposed to an outright ban in that area simply to avoid long and complicated discussions.

Comment: @Kaestur: There's an area where answers really must be judged on a case-by-case basis. To use a (contrived but fairly plausible) example: "How can I parse *X* from user input?" A unhelpful answer might be, "Use regular expressions". A spammy answer might be, "Use RELabs' [PowerRegExp2000](http://example.com/) library". A helpful form of the former might look like, "Use this expression: ...", while a less spammy form of the latter might be: "Using our PRE2000 library, you could simply write ..." - note the importance of providing a concrete answer vs. merely name-dropping.

Comment: @Shog9: I completely agree with your evaluations of those examples, I am only saying that the author of PRE2000 writing the "Using our PRE2000 library, you could simply write ..." answer should not be punished for such answers simply because it is his own product, even if such (helpful, of course) answers make up 100% of his user history. In fact, its quite plausible that he might have a separate account for the sole purpose of promoting this product. (Or maybe all he knows how to do is write regular expressions using this program's interface!)

Comment: @Pekka: there's a very real slippery slope here, IMHO. I'm very reluctant to advocate what amounts to mass censorship based on the *potential* for abuse, but once a user demonstrates a clear willingness to use any excuse to include a promotional link in his answers, I feel it is necessary to become more strict (lest we fall into the trap of giving a pass to advertisers who take the extra step of embedding their links in nominally on-topic answers).

Comment: @Shog9 I'm totally with you there - I expect fear huge discussions in every case that gets questioned, and think that may be too much to handle for everyone. To avoid that, I could live with a ban. Still, you're absolutely right.

Comment: I see I haven't said this before in this topic: -1: I don't think "our" is enough. Remember the number of users we have for whom English is not their first language. I'd prefer something more explicit like "Product X from my company", or "Product X (from the company I work for)".

Comment: @John: its clear you don't. Based on over a thousand views of this question, it seems to me that a significant part of the meta stack overflow audience does. What I haven't seen from you is a commitment to follow the policy as decided, regardless of what you think. I have made such a commitment. Why can't you?

Comment: @Ira: "don't" what? And, you still don't get Stack Overflow. Any policy is followed or not by individuals, to the extent they want to. There may be penalties if the policy is not followed, but it's up to the individual to decide what to do about that. I usually consider such policies to be the consensus of the community, and I usually try to adhere to that, while expressing any disagreement here in meta.

Comment: @John: Fine, register your disagreement.  What I object to is people acting on thier opinions, rather than on policies that seem to be accepted.

Comment: @Ira: "people acting on their opinions" is **exactly** how these sites are meant to work!

Comment: @Shog9: FWIW, that user now has 1.6k answers, and when I checked the first 30 far more than half of them had a link to his company's website. I find appalling — the more so since he's been annoying me with this in Usenet in the 90s already. SO is as high on google as it is because most of us, when answering, first and foremost try to give answers that help the user who asked, not ourselves. People like him are utilizing SO for advertising their business on our backs. I do resent that.

Answer (score 55):

As the "spammer" in question, I think it reasonable to rise to my own defense.

I think this question is a knee-jerk reaction to anything which has a whiff of commercialism, regardless of its utility.

Spam is defined by wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_(electronic) as
"use of electronic messaging systems (...) to send unsolicited bulk messages indiscriminately."

My responses are not indiscriminate.  Nor are they unsolicited.

While many of my posts (not all) might be argued as commercially biased,
they are NOT spam by this definition.  I challenge Michael or others to find a response which is not reasonably related to the question posted by the OP, or in fact even very good
answers.  The OP explicitly *requests* information and my responses are, I claim, on-topic.

The fact that they are upvoted by some readers indicate that they believe the
answer to be a reasonable answer.  The fact that OPs sometimes mark them as [best
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179879/where-does-context-sensitivity-get-resolved-in-the-c-compilation-process/1181773#1181773) shows that the OP believes he got a good response to his question.

Presumably if the post was made by somebody other than me, and the upvoters didn't know the difference, they would have upvoted anyway.

The implications are that my responses are useful to the OP and to the readers.

While I don't always (or even often) note that I am a principal at the company, my
icon bio data is extremely clear about my status and what my responses might mean.
(EDIT 72 hours after original post: A policy of making this connection explicit seems to have formed at about 12 hours after original post. Immediately thereafter I 
agreed in a number of comments to various responses to this question to implement
that policy on future answers, and revise previous answers as time permits. But the storm still rages on; read the rest of this post).

StackOverflow is useful because it gets answers for posters.  Objecting that an
answer has some commercial property doesn't negate the value of that answer if it
is relevant.  There are lots of answers that point to commercial products (e.g., Microsoft)
and they aren't marked as spam.  Why should posters not be able to get information
about useful results, just because my company is small and not a lot of people know
about it?  Nobody here seems to object to Microsoft getting what amounts to free air time, just because it has mindshare and therefore a non-MS person will provide a MS-biased answer.

While I do make a living from selling my tools, as far as I can tell everybody else at SO pretty much makes a living doing something that is commercially valuable. I'm passionate about the tools I build.  I believe they are extremely good at what they do, and of considerable value to the community.

I believe I am doing the community service.  I think you should allow any vendor (oh that awful word) that has *useful* responses to provide such responses.

*And I don't think this position should be repeatedly argued at SO, but rather become an explicitly embraced policy*.

You are of course allowed to have your own opinion about the quality and relevance of individual answers, and up/down vote answers accordingly.   You can downvote because you don't like commercial products, but I just think you are doing the OPs a disservice.

EDIT (12 hours after original post)
There now seems to be an additional *new* objection, which is that there is a large quantity of posts that refer to a (my) website.

1. If a question gets asked, then a reasonable answer should be a reasonable answer.  (Whether a question gets closed as a duplicate doesn't change this).
2. If the answers are reasonable, why does it matter what site they link to, or how many times that site is mentioned across all the SO answers?
3. In case anybody is paying attention, one of the reasons that I have a lot of answers *is because my company builds a lot of different tools* (using a common engine, check my bio if you want to know how this might be possible).

I think I'm getting singled out on this partly because I can provide a lot of useful answers.  That seems downright unreasonable.

EDIT (36 hours after original post)

There appears to be a proposal for a policy suggesting that marking one's own products explicitly in an answer would be A Good Thing.   I've agreed (see various comment threads where I seem to have to repeat my agreement repeatedly) to do this, and have in fact gone back and made changes to some of my posts.

However, it is entirely unclear that having a policy *proposal* is the same as

- having a policy
- having that policy be known
- having the policy be followed.  Consider a malcontent that doesn't like the policy.  (It may be obvious there are some working this SO thread). S(he) simply decides to take matters into her own hands and mark policy-following
  answer as spam anyway.  A blinking "somebody marked this as spam" is likely a magnet to a other malcontents, and thus you are likely to get a piling-on effect.  Small numbers of malcontents then produce almost predetermined outcomes; its called exponential decay.  For those malcontents, I suggest this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56223/has-there-been-an-uptick-in-spam-votes-against-established-questions/56224#56224).

I guess I'm not thrilled with how "community consensus" works. Welcome to the Internet.

In any case, I'll make the commitment that if policy is decided, "no self promotion", then I'll quit providing my-tool answers where my tools make sense, even if I think that's dumb. It'd be nice if the malcontents would make similar commitments about SO "policy".
I don't hold a lot of hope based on some of the vitriol present.

EDIT (48 hours after original).

In spite of the invective, I do not recall having answers I have provided removed as spam.  (It is possible there were some; early on in using SO it was pretty hard to tell why my rep went up or down).  What I find very disturbing is that since the start of *this* discussion, I have suddenly had a number of answers apparantly spam-buttoned-out, as indicated by several roughly 100-point drops in rep.  The coincidence strongly suggests causality.  Apparantly there are those that have read the thread(s) here and aren't interested in a positive policy outcome, and have simply gone vendetta.

EDIT (64 hours after the original)

Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158518/what-is-code-coverage/1382349#1382349) which I think has just been spam-tagged.  **I'd like somebody to explain to me how it is not a direct answer to the OP's question, regardless of attribution.**  This looks like outright spam-button abuse.
  (It was visible when first tagged; if you can no longer see this message, that's because it has been spam-deleted. Its harder to make your case when the evidence in your favor is deleted.)

EDIT (July 27).  The vigilantes are killing good answers.
Here's [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416880/aspect-oriented-programming-in-c/1512940#1512940) upvoted by the author of the question.

Comment: Your definition of spam doesn't matter. It's just that the option to report what the community feels is abusive happens to be labeled "spam". I only read [the first answer listed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230425/what-software-development-tool-most-changed-the-way-you-think-on-things/3263331#3263331), and sentences like "The consequences are a commercial program transformation tool [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.xxx/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) that is useful for [..]" are very much spam (even worse: *hidden* spam) in my definition.

Comment: @Arjan: *My* definition of spam? I took it from *Wikipedia* for heaven's sake. Regarding your "first answer listed": the specific question was, "What most influenced your career?" I responded specifically with a technical work that is NOT mine (and which is a *seminal* work in software engineering, sheesh!), and went on to explain that work has made me commit about **20** years of my life to that approach, which resulted in a particular piece of what I think of as spectacular machinery to implement the original paper's ideas. What, this didn't address the OP's original question smack on?

Comment: @Arjan: That example isn't particularly hidden when the sentence before (of which the "consequences" are) is "I've followed that idea into the software reengineering space, and bet the last 15 years of my career on it."

Comment: I guess my bad about misunderstanding [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230425/w/3263331#3263331) proves my point: in a long answer suddenly there's a link to a product you sell, where "The consequences are" implies that you're referring to something of your own? Anyway, [going down the list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224996/a/3225030#3225030)" *Check out the SD PHP Formatter. It formats both PHP and HTML code in the same script. Unlike many formatters, it will not break your code as it reformats. It acheives this by using a full PHP front end.* Plain spam to me.

Comment: @Arjan: That's a much better example.

Comment: @Arjan: And the OP's question was, "Does anyone know of a good tool for cleaning up/formatting PHP files?" which it directly answers, including additional information about what happens with most PHP formatters that I have encountered (being thrown together by PHP folks who are really lousy at parsing code reliably).  What part of my answer isn't a useful response to the question? You seem to be enumerating my responses and objecting, as I suggested as a challenge in my response above.   Fine, quote the original question and then your objection to my answer.

Comment: I really feel different. In my opinion, a recommendation by somebody who's not involved is totally different from a recommendation from the product owner. (Also, discussions about *the definition* of spam are, in my experience, a knee-jerk reaction of many people who're self-promoting in some hidden way.)

Comment: @Ira: Regarding the [discussion poll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230425/what-software-development-tool-most-changed-the-way-you-think-on-things), I think your answer is [much](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230425/-/3230467#3230467) [better](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230425/-/3230469#3230469) [than](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230425/-/3230447#3230447) [others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230425/-/3230486#3230486) [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230425/-/3232735#3232735), but the question is problematic in the first place.

Comment: @Arjan: The Internet community settled on the (wikipedia-quoted) definition of spam that it did after long and painful argument just like this, including the argument "I really feel different". I get a lot of hate from people coming to my site because my tools aren't "open source" or some version of free, I get a lot of complaints about "spam" from people that object to noting the existence of something that isn't free. But if it were free and the text were the same, how would that change the utility of the answer, even if self-promoted?

Comment: @Gnome: Thanks for the compliment on the poll-answer. As usual with SO, you are welcome to up or downvote the *question*, too :-}

Comment: @Ira: Regarding spam, *all* posts on SO are bulk (covered better elsewhere on Meta).  The [beautifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224996/are-there-any-recommended-tools-for-beautifying-php-html/3225030#3225030) answer mentioned above does sound more like marketing than answering; that distinction isn't always clear, but you do ignore half of that question (everything about Maven).  A simple change from "Check out SD PHP Formatter" to "Check out my company's PHP Formatter" should be enough to make your relationship explicit (in the answer itself, your bio often isn't sufficient).

Comment: I think this question is not about the definition of spam. The only reference to "spam" is that the option to *flag* posts is labeled as such.

Comment: @George: Exactly what I just tried to say.  Free-as-in-beer projects/products seem to have a lower requirement on disclosure because it's much harder to ascribe that self-serving motivation.

Comment: @George: You'd object if people with useful answers, although commercial, added them to asked questions?  I don't understand the objection.  I think you're objecting to clueless or useless responses, and there I agree.  (I'm not objecting to full disclosure, but I'd like SO to make the policy on this whole topic explicit).

Comment: What about my comment led you to believe that I'm voicing an objection to clueless/useless responses?  You are correct, I do object to such response.  However, that was not the point of my comment.  I suggest you read that again and stop looking for any angle that you can argue.  If you're not objecting to full disclosure, then why do you want an official policy?  The very fact that this issue has been brought up should be enough to motivate you to full disclosure. Instead, you want to play semantic games.

Comment: Here's a good example of a suspicious answer, that would've been better had you fully disclosed your relationship with the product you were plugging: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203376/unit-testing-framework-for-oracle-pl-sql/3225004#3225004

Comment: @George yes, full disclosure *would* have been better, no doubt. But he has shown his affiliation with the company in his profile from the start, and provided meaningful input on the question, and I can't bring myself to seeing this as too problematic. This is not somebody leaving "Hi use www.xyz.com itz great thx" posts by the truckload, of which there are many on all trilogy sites.

Comment: @George: I'm not interested in semantic games, and I didn't mean to misinterpret your answer (its 3am here). I'd be happy to do full disclosure, in the manner that Pekka has suggested. Up to this point in time, the policy was not clear and reasonable people could disagree about what was reasonable to write. Your turn to read my comments. I don't want to have this discussion again, which is why I'd prefer an official policy. Pekka's suggestion is great. But will stop the discussion? One answer is to try it for awhile. I'm game.

Comment: @Pekka That would not be enough to satisfy the policy you yourself have suggested in this very question.  It should be obvious that I don't believe it's enough.  I loot at user profiles, just out of curiosity, quiet often.  That said, I don't want to check every user profile for their affiliation.  Let me put it this way:  If I do check a user profile and discover an undisclosed affiliation to a product they recommended, I would not feel very good about the recommended product.  There's a reason used car salesmen are despised.

Comment: @Ira So, if this issue has come up in the past, why haven't taken to full disclosure?  Note, I don't think that would prevent all such discussions, but you would be in a better position to argue that you're not being sneaky.

Comment: @George it would not be enough under the policy I am suggesting, *but that policy is not in place yet.* As far as I can see, Ira's contributions were made in good faith, and never with the intent of hiding his affiliation. It's fine to talk about this and criticize him and work out better rules, but let's save up our indignation for *real* spammers.

Comment: @George: Are you satisfied with Pekka's recommendation? If so, I'll follow it, and even, as time permits, go back and adjust answers where the affiliation was unclear. (See revised answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203376/unit-testing-framework-for-oracle-pl-sql/3225004#3225004)

Comment: @Pekka I'm not trying to beat him over the head with a policy that is not actually in existence.  I take issue with his defense and arguments.  He's claims not to be playing semantic games, yet he's posted a link to a definition of spam.  He argues that he's not a spammer, when the point of this discussion is self promotion.

Comment: @Ira Yes, that would be good enough for me.

Comment: @George: I'm sorry, you'll have to forgive me for reading the phrase in the original question "are the spam flags accurate?" and believing that this discussion was about spam.

Comment: @Ira Fair enough, though there's no need to apologize. Simply stating that you misinterpreted the question is enough. (Now who's splitting hairs?) ;)

Comment: @Ira, (+1)  Even though your answer here is somewhat defensive (reasonbly, you *were* being attacked), it is obvious from your comments that you're going to be very reasonable and adult about all this, and make an attempt to fix the "problem". Well done!

Comment: @Ira: You might want to focus, initially, on [flagged](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged) posts.  (I see 7 of yours there now.)

Comment: @Gnome: thanks for the pointer.  I'd already fixed about half of those, during the discussion last night.

Comment: @Ira: 412 answers is free advertising. Either start paying for it, or at least announce your relationship to the company **in the answer**. Even "see my profile for my relationship to this company" would be enough for me.

Comment: @John:  I've already agreed to label my posts, according to a policy(?) that has been hashed out here. Is that policy not adequate?

Comment: @Ira: you really seem to not get how things work here. Yes, what the Community decides is pretty much "policy". And I look forward to seeing your new answers under this policy.

Comment: @John: I think I got the community-chooses-policy *concept*. I didn't understand why you chose to step in and make a remark about my compliance to the "new policy", when I fact I have clearly stated earlier in the thread that I would, and in fact have already started doing. I worry about "policy being decided" as a stable state; it appears subject to ongoing re-deciding (witness answer started by Shog9). One can argue that the discussion isn't old enough to be stable. Fair enough. So... when is the policy decided?

Comment: @Ira: as to when the policy is decided, it was already decided, and is already in the process of being decided, and will in the future be decided. The Community decides, and as the Community is a living, fluid entity, the decision will be living, and fluid. It will be enforced, as has already been done, by Community members voting on your answers, and maybe flagging them. That's all the process there is, here, and that's all the process that's needed by most users here. Some others need to wait until they're banned.

Comment: @Ira. It seems you've taken a bit of bashing here. I haven't gone back and read all your posts, but for what it's worth I support your position. I don't see anything wrong with suggesting your own products in an answer (provided they are in the context of the question). I don't see how quantity of links changes anything, provided the answers are in context and useful I don't see a problem with it. Clear disclosure is of course a good thing that I would encourage. I think your efforts to go back and bring your old posts into line with new [proposed] policy are admirable.

Comment: @Arjan: "Your definition of spam doesn't matter."  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56223/has-there-been-an-uptick-in-spam-votes-against-established-questions/56224#56224

Comment: @Simon: I suggest you read more of his posts, then you may feel differently about his position. I support that position in general, but having read many of his posts, feel that Ira is an exception to his own rule.

Comment: @John: I've read a few, admittedly some have been edited in the last day to include words like "our". Some specific ones that have been cited here as negative examples have been corrected too. I think it's just best to monitor on a case by case basis. If I ever see poorly disclosed, or unrelated spam links I always edit/flag them anyway as I'm sure most people do. He has now declared his position, (which I'm fine with). If in the future Ira goes against his now stated position he can be called up on that.

Comment: @Simon: that's good. That's what I'm doing as well. Watching his user feed, reading his answers, judging each one, publicly.

Comment: @Ira Why are you automatically assuming a vendetta?  For better or for worse, you're under the microscope now.  I'm not defending the deletions nor speaking to their validity.  However, just because those answers weren't considered problematic before doesn't mean that's the case under a new light.

Comment: @George: *Automatically* assuming? Its a plausible inference given the evidence.

Comment: @Ira Is it the only one?

Comment: @George: The *only* one spam tagged/removed? No, judging by my rep drop in the last 24 hours, some 10 or 12 of my answers have been spam removed. See my edit (48 hours) for one that looks spam-tagged is CLEARLY a direct answer to (at least part of) the OP's question.

Comment: @George: If you mean "is it the only plausible inference", maybe not. Have *you* suggestions for other plausible inferences that explain the facts?

Comment: About the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158518/what-is-code-coverage/1382349#1382349) shown in your *EDIT (64 hours after the original)* : nothing personal but this is the *perfect* example of the kind of answers *I* dislike. The OP is posting a question with 3 parts and it's like you only see the third point and jump on it to push your tools. This is exactly what *I* don't consider as a good answer but a commercial plug only and I'm indeed extremely tempted to flag it as spam.

Comment: @Pascal: The poster already had a number of very good answers to the first two parts; there was no need to answer them yet again. He *explicitly* asked for available tools. I provided some additional ones, that were not listed by another answer. *I gave him exactly what he wanted, and you think it is spam?*

Comment: @Ira: my only problem with your answer is that you need to edit it to show that you're recommending your own product. I suggest you do more than just add "our" in front of the product name. FYI, I neither flagged it nor downvoted it - if I do either of those, I'll update my answer to say so.

Comment: @Ira In retrospect, that was an ambiguous statement. That said, you should be able to infer from the context, as you stated that several answers were deleted. Specifically, I was asking if a vendetta is the only possible reason for the deletion(s). As for another possible answer, I'll quote myself: `For better or for worse, you're under the microscope now. I'm not defending the deletions nor speaking to their validity. However, just because those answers weren't considered problematic before doesn't mean that's the case under a new light.` You seem to be selective in your reading/arguments.

Comment: @Ira I don't consider you gave the OP *exactly* what he wanted, you gave him only a partial answer, justifying yourself here by the fact *others* already gave good answers. This is IMO a bad practice and using the work from other to justify a commercial plug only is clearly flirting with the limits of abuse (note that I still didn't downvote nor flagged your answer). As it has already been mentioned, `what if every one with a commercial product to plug started searching SO for every opportunity to plug their wares` ultimately saying it's ok because others already gave good answers?

Comment: @Pascal: He wanted to know what tools were used, as part of his question.  Do you feel compelled to answer *everything* requested by the OP every time, or do you judge and answer what you can add incrementally? I suspect the latter.  Do you insist that everyone else always provide a full answer?  I doubt it.  Why do you have a double standard?

Comment: @John: I didn't recommend the product. I *only* stated its existence, and considering that the OP wanted to know what ones were used (they are all used), the answer is/was reasonable. I changed the response to say "Our" in accordance with the "consensus" that seems to be building here. It is so breif that such now-present attribution can hardly be missed.

Comment: @Ira: you remind me of a drug addict who denies he has a problem and doesn't understand why nobody believes him. Seriously, "My product exists, but I'm not recommending it to you. I thought you should know about it so you could buy it, but I'm not recommending that you buy it." I'd be insulted that you think I'm that stupid, but it strikes me that maybe you can't help yourself, and don't realize what you're doing. Get some help, Ira.

Comment: @John: The OP didn't say he was going to buy, wanted to buy or didn't want to buy. He wanted to know what was used. Other answers had previosly provided a a collection of a list of tools.  Ours were not mentioned, but they are used.  I gave him a short list of our tools. Now he has a longer list. What part of "I answered his question directly" doesn't serve the exact purpose of SO?

Comment: @Ira What makes you think I have a double standard? I don't, bad is bad. However, recommendations from a product owner are "special" answers and I might be less tolerant with them, especially if I have the feeling that the author is somehow gaming the system. And the more we discuss, the more I think the answer I'm referring to is borderline.

Comment: @Pascal He just keeps digging a bigger hole.  The more he defends himself, the more I think that he has an ulterior motive. Especially because of the way he defends himself.

Comment: @Pascal: You appear to object if I don't provide a Whole Complete Answer to Every Aspect of the Question as Asked, and Only to those Asked Aspects, Every Time. I simply don't believe you yourself do that (nobody I know does that). So, you insist I Do, but You Don't Have To. I'd call that a double standard.

Comment: @Pascal: I will say you gave a nice answer to a question I asked about Hibernate before we got crossways here.

Comment: Just throwing my two cents in here (a little late), but I was disappointed to see Ira's posts keep rising to the top of the spam flags.  He seemed to have conducted himself well in the individual answers I saw, with his affiliation disclosed and with the product being very relevant to the question.  I agree with the others who have stated that he's contributed to the site not with money through advertising but with his own time in providing quality content.

Comment: @George, your comment of "Especially because of the way he defends himself." bothers me.  Do only the guilty fervently defend their position?  When I read your comment I thought of the Salem witch trials where the only proof of innocence was to die.  In this case, we can infer from your comment that you feel he's guilty *because* he's defending himself so strongly.  The alternative would be providing no defense which would lead to the charge of 'If he were innocent, he would defend himself.'  No wonder the man feels like he's between a rock and a hard place.

Comment: @kellyfrench I was referring to *way* he defended himself not the amount of energy he put into his defense or the simple fact that he was defending himself.  You are correct that just because one defends oneself strongly does not make one guilty.  That said, if it looks like a duck, walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it's probably a duck.

Comment: @George, fair enough, thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: @PascalThivent I'd agree with your objection to the partial answer referring to his tool if it were the first answer, maybe even the second, because having answers reduces a question's visibility relative to questions with no answers (likewise multiple answers vs. one). So, early answers need to be complete. However, it's common practice to post answers that provide additional relevant information after a question has other answers. As long as he provides an actual explanation rather than just a link, I don't see the problem--especially in cases where there's already an accepted answer.

Comment: @IraBaxter As a noob when it comes to building parsers and compilers, your answers have been extremely valuable for me, and I'm glad that you're willing to share your knowledge. It's embarrassing to see the ill-treatment you get from some high-rep users on this thread.

Comment: @Gabriel:  Thanks for the compliment.  This was a rough patch.  We collectively seem to be past it; I haven't had a lot of trouble with SO.   OTOH,  I've posted a lot less over the last several years, partly because there are still a remarkable number of people that downvote for nontechnical reasons.

Answer (score 46):

**If the best answer to the question happens to be a commercial product, it seems entirely irrational to me that it can't be posted by any user.**

Forbidding the person most likely to be familiar with the product from doing so would seem to go against the real goal - *getting good answers.*

**That said, posting your own product without disclosures is essentially misrepresenting something - most readers will assume that your opinion is unbiased, and it's not.**

Still, this seems pretty easily solvable:

1. **Post good, relevant answers, and if they happen to be about your product, so be it.**  That means that it's okay to list your own product if it really meets the criteria, but if it's wildly off what the poster asked for, it's SPAM.
2. **Clearly disclose conflicts and biases.**    While I think "our" or "my" probably conveys it, some folks obviously don't, so why debate it:  You're only posting your own stuff when it's appropriate, and helpful, and it will make people love you, right?   What's the harm in getting used to pasting this:   (Disclosure:  I [work for/own/whatever] the company that makes it, but I think it's a logical fit for your need).

It seems as though the last thing you want is some guy who knows that his app has a rarely-discussed feature to solve the problem sitting around waiting for some other user to discover it.   On the other hand, those that blindly post their own product to any borderline-related query should be down-voted and flagged.

Comment: Except that this does not work. There are many cases where a commercial plug is not the best answer and doesn't even really answer the question. This happens all the time (I can find many examples of "How can I do this with X" - "With my Y you can"). This is tiring.

Comment: @Pascal I largely avoided flagging anything since I'm on the fence about it (hence posting this question in the first place), but I did flag [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166198/with-gcov-is-it-possible-to-merge-to-gcda-files/3188843#3188843) for exactly that reason. The OP asked for a tool to combine GCDA files generated by GCC from C/Obj-C sources on Mac OS, and the answer was for a tool that doesn't combine GCDA files, doesn't work with Obj-C, and doesn't run on Mac OS

Comment: @Pascal:  I don't see your disagreement here.  Jaydles says the answers should be good and relevant, and you're objecting to irrelevant answers.  Moreover, the "what you really want" answer is well established on SO, since lots of people overspecify the problem or are going down a path that doesn't work.

Comment: @Mrozek: and the reason I responded is that guy wasn't making any progress with the solution he had. Based on the empty set of answers he has, he would otherwise have nothing. If you can't get an answer to the question as posed, then a reasonable response is to change the question. The tool I mentioned didn't do GDCA files. It *did* handle GCC, which was one of his desiradata. You might object to my answer, but it is *the* only answer he got, it addressed the technical issue he faced, if not the specific detail. And, he thanked me for the answer.

Comment: @David I'm not disagreeing, I'm saying *"getting good answers"* only doesn't work in practice. ***I*** don't have any interest in pushing a product Y when a question about product X is asked. However, someone commercially involved with Y (payed product/consulting/support/whatever) has an interest in doing so and I've seen this pattern happening many times. See the examples of this [previous question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55914/is-it-ok-to-push-your-own-product-on-so). I don't call this good answers, I call this spam. Yet it occurs and will continue to occur.

Comment: @Pascal: *You* may *call* it spam, but that doesn't make it spam. It is unreasonable to redefine words with well defined meetings. Theres a standard definition used by most of the internet, hashed out after a long time by groups of people collectively smarter than you or I. I won't repeat it for the Nth time here, you're a big boy and can go look it up for yourself. If you chose a better label for your objection, I might feel better about discussing your objections.

Answer (score 15):

It's unpaid advertising, pure and simple.

**I** would call it spam, simply because there's no such thing as a private reply on SO: *every* answer addresses every reader who finds that question. But if that makes you uncomfortable, then fine: **it's just rude**.

SO provides an extensive system for placing advertisements in designated locations. If you have a commercial product that you wish to promote on SO, [**then pay for it**](https://stackoverflow.com/about/contact). It's folks buying ads that keep the site up and under continual improvement.

**There is more than enough angst and controversy over the official, clearly marked, *paying-for-the-site-to-keep-running* ads - clogging the answers themselves with unofficial, unmarked ads should *never* be seen as acceptable.**

Flag as spam or flag for moderator attention, lest this become a cancer on the site...

---

#### Clarification

Look, I'm not saying they aren't *well-written* advertisements. I'm not saying they're completely off-topic, or that the tools being promoted couldn't, for some users in some situations, prove useful. Advertising doesn't *have* to be cringe-inducing - that's just what we're used to, because there's so much of it around. But take a look at something like [Eric Sink's blog](http://www.ericsink.com/) - he writes about source control, running a software company, advertising, and of course his own company and its products. There are some great articles... And it's brilliant advertising, since people *want* to link to them. The "Joel on Software" site is the same thing, fun to read while at the same time a huge series of ads.

I don't have a problem with good ads. I'm not *anti-advertising*.

But SO isn't *anyone's* personal blog. Questions from people struggling to use competing products shouldn't be seen as [an open invitation to hawk your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166198/with-gcov-is-it-possible-to-merge-to-gcda-files/3188843#3188843). SO users, as a group, tend to be rather trusting - the starting assumption when reading an answer is that it is actually intended to solve the problem described in the question.

I consider the abuse of this trust to be poisonous. And I have no sympathy for systematic, long-term abuse, *regardless* of what name you give it. I regret that I have only five flags a day...

Comment: Are you branding all commercial promotion as spam, or only unmarked ones? Because as a user who actually had a problem solved by a commercial suggestion (by a user whose name was the same as the company), I can't really agree with completely disallowing all commercial suggestions. Sometimes, the only tool to solve a problem is one that will cost money. Which then means, are free solutions or solutions that sponsor SO the only ones that are valid?

Comment: @Grace: I'm saying it's a red-herring. This has nothing to do with commercial vs. non-commercial software - I've promoted commercial software in answers, **just not software I make money off of**. It's also not about self-promotional answers occasionally being useful: *of course* they're useful, some of the time, for some small percentage of users - if spam didn't *work* (find its target), it wouldn't be a problem because no one would bother posting it! This is a case of a user abusing the popularity of the site to promote his own business - everything else is just a distraction.

Comment: Alright. I can respect that perspective.

Comment: Spam works by blasting millions of useless answers to people that didn't ask for anything, in the hopes that some tiny percentage may have some faint interest.    Answering people's direct questions with directly relevant data, even if it is a commercial answer, doesn't look anything like that.   If we follow your path, Microsoft gets tons of free mentions simply because they're huge and their advertising got to you in the past.   And I'll remark that its folks providing answers for free that allows SO to even do that crass commercial advertising that it does :-}

Comment: @Shog9 Well put.

Comment: @Ira I see you're still defending your narrow, self-serving definition of spam.  Bad form, man. Bad form.

Comment: @George: It sure looks like we disagree. But this argument raged for quite a long time on the internet, and the definition I quoted was the conclusion that many, many, people came to after long discusssions like this. My position is what I am doing isn't spamming. By the mostly widely accepted definition (back to Wikipedia you go), it is not. And I'll swear you said this whole discussion wasn't about spam.  I've even agreed to mark my posts in a way that you seemed to accept.

Comment: @Ira As far as I'm concerned the discussion is not about spam. So, IMO you should stop talking about spam. That said, if someone wants to consider such posts as spam, so be it.  I don't think that's an unfair point of view.  Shog9 puts it well when he states: `I would call it spam, simply because there's no such thing as a private reply on SO: every answer addresses every reader who finds that question. But if that makes you uncomfortable, then fine: it's just rude.` Further discussions of the definition of spam only serve to undermine your position. That was the point of my previous comment.

Comment: @Ira: The folks providing answers for free that allows SO to sell advertising accept that such advertising is the cost of having a well-run place to trade answers; it's been a part of the site since its inception, and those who aren't comfortable with it are under no obligation to post here. Piggy-backing the promotion of your own products on the popularity wrought by other users is another matter entirely, but I have as little hope of convincing you of this as the good folks on USENET had of convincing Canter and Seigel that flooding the system with offers of paid legal aid was in poor taste.

Comment: @Shog9: I don't remember any of Canter/Seigel victims asking specifically for the kind of help they could provide, and that's a rather crucial distinction. I think you have made a serious category error. With that set mindset, its clear I'm not going to convince you, either.

Comment: @Ira: I seem to recall an interview with Canter where he recounted receiving *thousands* of positive responses. As I said to Grace above, the problem with spam *is not* that it fails to find an accepting audience... It's the collateral damage, the waste of time and resources, and the resulting loss of trust in the system as a whole. See also: the tragedy of the commons.

Comment: @Shog9: Give me a break. Canter's recipients didn't ask for his spam. And I'm sure if you poll them, the vast majority would have said his "message" was unwanted and irrelevant to their lives, let alone what they might have been thinking +-1 day from recieving his message. The audience here at SO is *actively* asking for information, and I believe you will find that my answers (and those of other *relevant* commercial suppliers) are welcome as plausible answers to their question. Your example is so far beyond a reach that I think you damage the part of your position which is defensible.

Comment: @Ira You could make a similar argument about recruiters on dice.com.  However, now that dice.com is overrun with recruiters, it's become next to useless.  Except to get noticed by recruiters. yay =/

Comment: I'm a little bit surprised about your reaction, @Shog. Spam is commercial, that does not mean that commercial is spam. You are right, that Ira is not paying for his "ads" on SO, but if you pay for them, you show your commercial to all users, if they search for this particular product or not. Ira is answering questions where his products can help the asker to solve his problem and I really have no idea what's wrong with that. Do you suggest that the question asker has to wait till someone else, not working in Ira's company, tells him that Ira's product exists? That does not make sense to me.

Comment: @Ladybug If we let the marketers have their way, we'd have commercials playing on the inside of our eyelids.

Comment: @Ladybug No, that's Shog9's solution. He takes a hard line, which I can respect. I was merely making the point that if we let marketers have their way, we'd be screwed. So, we do exactly what we're doing here in this question, put up resistance. Now, to your point of commercials not being spam, why do you think AdBlock is such a popular Firefox addon? Maybe it's because so many sites aren't happy with just having banner ads, they now try to squeeze them in everywhere they possibly can. Taken as a whole, that's spam, pure and simple. Ads here on SO are a necessary evil. But they're still evil.

Comment: @George: I tried to explain to you, that it is *not* a solution. You will not solve the problem with that. And if you think, that ads, which are financing a free service, are evil, then I think we two will not come to an agreement. So let us stop here.

Comment: @Ladybug, I think George described it as "a **necessary** evil".

Comment: @Arjan: He describes them as "still evil". Ads on SO make it possible, that we do not have to deal with something like expert-exchange. So there are many adjectives which come into my mind to describe these ads, but none of them is *evil*.

Comment: @Ladybug *Sigh* @Arjan has it correct.  That's not evil as in Google evil, but as in a *necessary* evil.  Yeah, they're still "evil," by virtue of being called a necessary evil. If they're so great, and everyone loves them so much, why is the reward for gaining 200 rep reduced advertising?  I agree that ads are necessary on SO.  However, there's also some chance that they're relevant to my needs as a programmer; unlike punching a monkey to "win" some "prize."  (Oh, lets not forget that "gravity-defying," clear plastic ball; currently being marketed on TV for $20! Yeah, advertising is great.)

Comment: @George: Sorry, but I'm totally lost on both, your definition of *evil* and your definition of *spam*. Maybe we should skip those and come back to how to make it possible, that people like Ira can answer question and mentioning their products as possible solution. Because forbidding it, will not solve anything.

Comment: *sigh*... Look, this is what I was trying to avoid. Don't call it "spam", don't call it "evil", don't bother with *any* label you can't nail down - arguing semantics is pointless. *Look at the facts*, go through the answers, tell me how questions are being honestly answered by linking to a non-free product in answers to questions explicitly asking for free tools, or vague claims that some product could solve a specific problem if the proper definitions were written (followed by a link and *no* definitions). Ira is a good salesman - but the fact remains, these are sales pitches, *not* answers.

Comment: @Ladybug That's already being/been discussed in this question. I thought you were up to speed and I was simply going into a side discussion about advertising. I won't go into my definition of 'evil' and 'spam,' as you seem to expect neat, dictionary definitions. Unfortunately, not all definitions are neat. Some words have a list of definitions a mile long, which such variance that one has to wonder how they can refer to the same word. Yes, you can accuse me of being loose with my definitions, but that's English and most any language. They evolve and change. @Shog9 sorry for derailing things.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm on the trolley.  They do seem like sales pitches.  Put it this way, many of those answers make my skin crawl like a used car salesmen would.

Comment: So this one just got deleted as "spam": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224752/how-to-navigate-around-and-get-familiar-with-large-c-or-c-code-base/3224793#3224793.  It answered the question posed by the OP directly, IMHO a very useful way.   Yes, I mentioned that our tools *support* this method well, and why.  I don't know if other similar tools, actually support this method. (You might accuse me of being biased, but I've looked at lot of other similar tools and they don't appear to do that. Note I didn't say that.)  So, I think SO is losing really good answers.

Comment: I will also note that *until today* not one of my posts has been tagged as spam. I conclude this discussion has started some kind of vigilante mob *in spite of the fact that there is a proposed policy* that everybody but Shog (and weirdly George who seemed to support it last night) seems OK with.

Comment: Everybody? No, not everybody agrees with Pekka's proposal. I explicitly would like some limit to be included, or at least *a statement* (yes or no) on such limit, given this question's subject. (To me, Pekka's proposal seems to only focus on disclosure, which has already been covered [and voted for](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15787/how-do-i-mention-my-own-products-in-answers/15791#15791) in the questions Michael referenced in this very question.) Apart from that: this very question was asked *because of the flags*, while obviously that proposal came after that?

Comment: And given the volume of users and opinions at a place like SO, it will never be the case that everybody agrees.  So, how does the policy get stable?  Or is it, "one man, always a possible future veto"?

Comment: (I don't understand what happens to some of the edits here. Maybe I mis-saved). What I meant to say above was, "That until today, not one of my posts was *removed* as spam; I have no way of knowing (until very recently) whether any were tagged as spam therefore ... vigilantes... "

Comment: "vigilantes" is sort of a useless term when applied to SO. Everyone votes according to what is right in their own eyes - SO *runs on* vigilantism. Worth keeping in mind when discussing things here on Meta: even if it appears that a consensus has been reached, it can take months or longer to get any real buy-in from SO users, simply because the vast majority of SO users aren't browsing Meta on a regular basis.

Comment: @Ira I don't understand, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224752/how-to-navigate-around-and-get-familiar-with-large-c-or-c-code-base/ was closed as a duplicate on the 13th of July, i.e. 5 days ago. I can clearly see your answer in the question.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @George: Doesn't matter when the question was "closed", it still gets traffic.   I see a *deleted* answer, which I thought I provided a link to, above.   It might surprise you (well, maybe not) that I in fact provided two *really different* answers to that question. You likely see the "search engine" response; I'm talking about the "test coverage" response, which is the marked as "deleted by Community".

Comment: @Ira For the record, I agree with the idea (and generally Pekka's proposed policy) on full disclosure when suggesting a product with which one has a connection.  That is not necessarily the same as my thoughts on the practice of promoting one's commercial wares in answers.  I respect Shog9's hardline stance on the matter, but personally would take one step away from that, because someone may truly have a commercial product that is useful for the person asking the question.  That said, "give them an inch, they take a mile."  Shog9 is merely trying to nip that whole problem in the bud.

Comment: @Shog: My remark about vigilantism is the suprising sudden co-occurrence this SO question and discussion and the flood of "spam" clicks. A less reasonable person than I might conclude there was a causality link.

Comment: @Ira re: deleted answer.  The only response, from you, visible to me in that question begins with "A language sensitive-search tool can make finding your way around easier..."  At both the link you provided and the one that I used.

Comment: @George: It may be that SO only displays deleted answers to its authors, I'm not the expert here.  When I do a "View Source", I see this for the deleted answer:
 <div class="vote">
    <input type="hidden" value="3224863">
    <span class="vote-up-off" title="This answer is useful (click again to undo)">up vote</span>
    <span class="vote-count-post">-5</span>
...               <div class="deleted-answer-info">locked by <a href="/users/-1/community" >Community</a><span class="mod-flair" title="moderator">&#9830;</span> <span title="2010-07-18 19:36:10Z" class="relativetime">3 hours ago

Comment: @George: he had two answers posted in that question, the second one has been deleted. It began, *"Often what you need to do is the find the code related to a certain feature F so that you can work on that feature. One way to accomplish this is with test coverage tools."*

Comment: @Ira Correct, as the owner you can still see the deleted response.  I've only deleted one answer, so that didn't come to mind when looking at the question.

Comment: @Shog9: quoting you: "I regret that I have only five flags a day...
"  Its clear that in spite of the fact that there seems to some kind of consensus on the policy (based on the vote count for the policy proposed versus that on your answer here), that you won't have any part of it.

Comment: @Shog9: Regarding "struggling to use a competing product" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166198/with-gcov-is-it-possible-to-merge-to-gcda-files/3188843#3188843 ... You say it is poisonous. Why don't we ask the OP? Oh, his comment is "Thanks very much Ira. ..." Seems like you and he disagree on what poisonous is, just as you disagree with the defintion of spam and evil and apparantly any other word that isn't working for you. Make sure you use your five flags a day. I hope it provides you satisfaction.

Comment: @Ira: at the time I write this, the question has been *viewed* less than 400 times, with under 30 votes between the top two answers. That's not bad for a weekend post on Meta, but it's hardly an overwhelming indication of community opinion. If you agree with Pekka's suggestions, *then go implement them!* As for me, I stand by what I wrote - you're intelligent and a good salesperson, but your actions on SO disgust me. Whether others agree or disagree will be borne out in their future actions here and on SO itself...

Comment: Oh - and nice job cutting off the relevant portion of that comment, the bit where he states that *changing platform isn't an option*. So both you (as stated in your answer) and Joe (as stated in his comment) recognized that not only did your answer *fail to answer the question*, but that it wasn't even relevant to the situation of the person asking it. But there it sits...

Comment: @Shog9: I have repeatedly said I would implement the policy. (Read other threads). I have already said I would even go back and change the answers and done some of that aleready.  What part of "I agree" with the policy here haven't you heard? Sheesh. Based on your remarks, as far as I can tell, you won't honor that policy anyway.

Comment: @Shog9:  I was very clear in my response that it would not probably help him, but that it did implement the kind of idea he needed.  It didn't appear that what he needed he could get in his world, but there was some hope in that the ideas were actually implemented somewhere?  Why are you minimizing the fact that he thanked me for the answer?

Comment: @Ira: what part of "community moderation" don't *you* understand? I get *one* vote - same as everyone else. I'm stating my objections here so they're out in the open: agree or disagree, anyone who cares can be aware of *why* I'm voting. I *don't* agree with Pekka's solution, but if you do then act accordingly - it's largely irrelevant as far as I'm concerned (I would prefer all links/recommendations not directly requested by the OP to be removed), but again - I'm *only one vote*.

Comment: As for the thanks you got, I've explained at least twice now that the *general usefulness* of such advertising is immaterial - if it isn't needed to answer the question (and especially if it *doesn't* answer the question), then it shouldn't be posted.

Comment: As I commented on the above answer, a vendor can either pay for advertising by giving SO money, at which point they can just forget about it, or they can have an employee post useful answers that promote their product. As long as the answers are in fact useful, they are still contributing to the community, just using time instead of money. If they are not useful, they will be voted down or deleted. Why is special action necessary?

Comment: @Shog9: Yes, you're only one vote. And that I don't mind; you are welcome to your opinion.  What I do mind is the apparant "I'm a member of the community doing my duty" but with the apparant intention of ignoring what the community decides, if it doesn't decide your way.  Or, maybe I'm being uncharitable, and in fact you'll commit to honoring the community choice, once it is clear?

Comment: Note: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56223/has-there-been-an-uptick-in-spam-votes-against-established-questions/56224#56224

Comment: @Ira: you're still missing the point... What's discussed here serves only to establish some guidelines. Ultimately, the opinion of the community is indicated by how we vote on SO itself! I'm going to spam-flag posts I consider spam, down-vote posts I consider unhelpful, up-vote posts I consider useful... Anything else would be dishonest! That said, if it becomes crystal clear that gratuitous promotional linking is considered acceptable, I will take that into consideration. I have no idea what you're implying with that link - I'm certainly not flagging posts I don't consider to be spam...

Comment: @Kaestur: where am I advocating "special action"? Flag spam, ask moderators to intervene if it becomes excessive - that's pretty much *standard operating procedure*. Unless you're confusing "generally useful" with "useful in solving the problem described in the question" - much as I think tasty waffle recipes would prove useful to users struggling with Java, I think we can both agree that off-topic answers should be frowned upon.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm not sure this has been covered *specifically* yet, and I'd like to know your opinion. 
If I go on SO and I identify a need that (let's say) actually exists. For example (ignore competing products) **Q: "Does anyone know a good tool for converting CSV to XML?"** and I notice that the question comes up often in various forms. So I *create* such a tool commercially. The tool *exactly* answers the question, because I created it to do so. IF I answer the question as such, is it acceptable? **A: "My company develops 'Magical Product'(link) which fulfills your purpose."**

Comment: ... the idea being that if someone else had provided that answer it would be acceptable, because they aren't personally involved. But my in-depth knowledge of the product would mean that my answer is *more* pertinent, although my stake in selling it would mean that my answer is suspect.

Comment: @devinb: I don't really have a problem with that, so long as the answer actually satisfies the conditions laid out in the question. I'm much less confident in the suitability of such answers for questions of the form, "How can I accomplish *X*?" where the OP doesn't specify if he's looking for a tool or merely an appropriate algorithm - these are perhaps not very good questions to begin with, so promoting commercial solutions could be acceptable *provided they actually explain how to achieve the desired results* (e.g., "jQuery lets you do so with the following selectors" vs. "use jQuery!").

Comment: I'm much more skeptical of answers that mention / link to a commercial product unnecessarily, or *in lieu of* a real explanation. At best, these are the equivalent of the classic, "I have an answer - read my blog for details" answers; at worst, they're just piggybacking ads on a (otherwise-good / otherwise-bad) answer. **Examples:** "As I found when writing [Pool Party Poker IV](http://example.com/), the Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm works best when...", "Your problem is common; a novel solution is described in the whitepaper found at [Purchase Enterprise Hello World](http://example.com/)..."

Comment: @Shog9: You appear to be flagging posts that *you* consider spam.  We've already been around the block on your abuse of the word spam.   The link to Atwoods post was to show you that somebody else other than me uses the definition of spam that the Internet community decided, not what suits you.

Comment: @Shog9: I note you seem to have avoided answering the question about committing to what the community has decided.

Comment: @Ira: In your mind, it's not spam because *it's you doing it* - I'm unlikely to change your mind on this, and so I'm not about to waste words trying. Call it whatever you want, and pick and choose whichever parts of Wikipedia articles *don't* apply to you - whatever makes you feel good about yourself. I'm not flagging posts indiscriminately, and I'm not flagging posts where the content and links are actually on-topic - if you actually believe that linking to your site from any question containing certain keywords is appropriate, then report me (team@stackoverflow.com) and be done with it.

Comment: @Ira: I've noticed you seem to have avoided reading my responses. What exactly do you think indicates the decision of the community?

Comment: @Shog, I agree completely (not often the case with me). But it is a very delicate balancing act. The problem on SO is that we are all familiar with the product we deal with most. C#, SharePoint, WPF, or whatever. An example would be if someone from the jQuery team was on SO. It would be SO obvious to her that jQuery is *the* correct answer, but their (*correct*) assessment would be called into question because of their domain knowledge. Anyway, I think your stance is too harsh, but as always, your logic and arguments are impeccable.

Comment: @devinb: thanks. You make a good point WRT areas of expertise... I've been going through Ira's answers (at roughly two pages a day), and while there are a fair number of cases I consider blatantly abusive, there are as many or more where I lack sufficient knowledge of the topic to make a fair call, and so cannot in good conscience vote or flag. Ultimately, those users most invested in a particular area on SO will be the ones to judge such answers - which is as it should be.

Comment: @Shog9: By 'special action' I meant that I interpreted your statements as meaning "someone promoting their own product should be treated differently from someone promoting a third-party product," which I disagree with. If you are indeed only marking inappropriate/off-topic answers in an objective manner, that's great. I am just a little bit worried by your tone. Going through and downvoting all posts by a certain user is clearly abusive; going through all posts by a certain user deliberately looking for posts to downvote may or may not be, but it sure doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: @Kaestur: I don't like it either, to be honest. But there's something fishy here, and I prefer to work within the system if at all possible - if this doesn't work (for whatever definition of "work" you feel appropriate), then SO has bigger problems than one link-happy user (and it'll be up to moderators / site admins to determine what, if anything, needs to be done about it).

Comment: @Shog9:  "Working within the system" presumably means respecting policy decisions made by the group.  You don't seem interested in what the the group thinks; you appear to want to have it your way regardless of the consensus.  You have yet to make a commitment to what the community thinks is reasonable.

Comment: good grief, @ira... I'm here to participate in a discussion on how this sort of behavior should be perceived and handled, not co-sign your little campaign. If you think, honestly, that you understand what the community wants from you, then act accordingly; if you don't , and can't handle the uncertainty, then pay for guaranteed, free-from-user-veto, ad space... Otherwise, take your chances like everyone else.

Answer (score 14):

It's simple honesty and courtesy to state affiliations. And if it's not the law yet (in the USA) it probably soon will be. See [FTC Moves to Unmask Word-of-Mouth Marketing - Endorser Must Disclose Link to Seller](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2006/12/11/AR2006121101389.html)

Answer (score 13):

SO and friends exist to get good answers to questions.

Anything that causes more and better answers is good.  Anything that stifles useful answers is bad.

I'm firmly opposed to any policy that restricts anybody from giving a good, relevant, answer to a question, just on the basis of irrelevant details like personal involvement.  I agree that attribution is necessary, and I know that it's possible to deliver irrelevant and bad answers while recommending software, but if I have a problem and somebody out there sells a product that will solve my problem, I don't want any policy stopping that somebody from recommending it.

Comment: +1. I agree. However, out of 412 answers that present his products as an appropriate answer, there are bound to be some cases where his product is only _related_ to the answer and is not, itself, an answer. I'm keeping an eye out for those. If his products are the answer, or even potentially the answer, then that's great, and the kind of contribution we should encourage. If not, then not.

Answer (score 8):

I have just flagged as spam, Ira's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360673/any-valid-reason-for-code-duplication/1361308#1361308) to [Any valid reason for code duplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360673/any-valid-reason-for-code-duplication). While I appreciate his willingness to edit his previous answers, I do not think that adding the word "our" before his product names is adequate.

It just barely calls out his relationship to the product in question. In fact, I wonder if it will even be meaningful to some for whom English is not their first language.

Furthermore, reading his answer, I did not find it responsive to the question. The fact that he has a product that helps detect duplicate code does not respond to the question of whether there is ever a valid reason for duplicate code. It's great that there was a solution for the problem, but *nobody asked for a solution to the duplicate code problem*.

I will continue following his user feed.

---

Today, I used the 10k tools for the first time in a while, and noticed there were 25 flags. I clicked over there just for the heck of it, and saw several of Ira's answers on the first page. I was inspired.

So, since I said I'd do this publicly, here's the reasoning:

- In his answer to [Metaprogramming how much is too much?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028768/metaprogramming-how-much-is-too-much/2344070#2344070), written over six months after the previous answer, he starts by answering "There's never enough". That was the only thing in the answer that is responsive to the question. The rest describes how metaprogramming came to be, describes the "ideal world" with respect to metaprogramming, then states that the ideal world is provided by his product!
- In his answer to [What’s a good desktop-based code review tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542645/whats-a-good-desktop-based-code-review-tool/2546819#2546819), he goes straight for the spam flag, presenting his company's diff tool as though it were a code review tool. The OP did not ask about diff tools!
- His answer to [Best Diff Tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool/1006110#1006110) is better, but only because the OP asked for diff tools, and asking for the "best" such tool leaves an opening for those who think their product is the best. I'll grant that Ira does describe those features of his product that make it a contender for "best". I may even try it myself, as I've wanted a language-sensitive diff tool for decades. I did not flag this one as spam.

There are three more flagged answers, but the rest are not on the first page, so I'll let them slide for now.

Comment: Not responsive to the question? You and I sure live in different worlds. I've been building clone detectors for 15 years (see my tech paper http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.70.1272&rep=rep1&type=pdf), and what I told him was what I learned about clones. What I said was that yes, there were valid reasons, but to make them useful you needed a tool to track them. And, showed him a link to a tool that did just that, complete with examples. At least two people originally thought the answer worth upvoting. Looks like you've gone from "dislike" to "vendetta".

Comment: The "policy" being discussed says 'I suggest that using the word "our" or "my" be enough'.  The example used in the policy is "Our Quadruptron IV can do this". The text in the answer is "See our CloneDR for a tool".  So, you are apparantly objecting to the proposed policy.  And that last bit... you're insulting my ability to write English.  OK, you win.

Comment: @John... OK, we've sparred enough. I don't have many "enemies" in life, and surprisingly I've somehow made you into one. Are you willing to chat by phone for few minutes to help clear the air? You can send me a phone number via my email address at my icon, or ask me to send you mine.

Comment: @Ira: the question wasn't about clones! It was about whether there were valid reasons for duplicate code. The fact that there are tools for detecting duplicate code doesn't address the question of whether there are valid reasons for it.

Comment: @Ira: On your second comment, I and others have repeatedly attempted to make clear that "policy" is, at best, a description of how the Community behaves, not some fixed set of rules. I have done you the courtesy of explaining my reasoning on this, and doing so publicly.

Comment: @Ira: I don't know what air there is to clear. I don't know how much more clear I can be than what I've said here, publicly, for all to see and downvote. What could I possibly say to you in private that would be of more value to you than what I've already said in public?

Comment: @John: *clones* are *defined* to be duplicate code, which makes it *precisely* about clones. The OP said his code was full of duplicated code!  If you want to misinterpret the technical definitions, then you can claim the answer is irrelevant. That's not a legitimate argument. You can always find a reason, if you are willing to twist the definitions or the facts.

Comment: @Ira, the bottom line of his question is "What could be a valid reason for duplicating code?" Does your product help answer that question? Your answer suggests that your product can help him find (and presumably remove) duplicates. He didn't ask about that!

Comment: @John: So you want a literalist interpretation of every question? SO would be a pretty useless place. ("Is there a tool that does X?" your response would be "Yes").  Most people asking questions have a specific question, and they're glad to hear a specific answer.  Many answerers go well beyond the literal question, and try to provide help and advice about the trouble the questioner is about to have.  Peoples asking about clones, especially "my code has a lot of clones (implied call for help)" should reasonably get help.  ...

Comment: @John: ... If you know where clones are, your understanding and maintenance problems go down. Clone detectors are needed; they manage the #1 software smell, ask the refactoring guys. Maybe you don't think this answer is warranted. OK, fine. I've been working with duplicated code and related tools for 15 years. I think the answer is entirely justified.

Comment: @Ira: Sorry, man, I've got to call BS on that. I've been in the Software Product space, as well as most others, and, sorry, but you're dreaming if you feel that's responsive. He didn't ask anything about managing duplicate code. You might have _asked_ him in a comment whether he was interested in managing his duplicates and if he said yes, then your answer would have been responsive - otherwise, no.

Comment: @John: So you are proposing that people provide the shortest possible answer that might satisfy a question? Most conversations anticipate the other party's response and provide answers to expected questions. If your wife asks, "Are you coming home soon?" you could answer "No" and just stop. But your wife would likely kill you if you followed it up with, "Would be interested in knowing what time?". You might not like my anticipation of next questions, but that's different than its an unreasonable response.

Comment: @Ira: I propose that you, or anyone else who answers a question, take the time to find out what the OP actually wants. In your case, you should go out of your way to make sure he actually wants product recommendations from the product vendor. I saw no reason to believe the OP in this question had any interest in your product, or any other product. If you thought he might be interested in products but just didn't clearly say so, then ask for clarification in a comment. Until it's clarified, you should not be hawking your product to such users.

Answer (score 6):

I have nothing against commercial products, but I also promote full and visible disclosure for free services or personal blogs. Hence, I think *undisclosed* and *somehow hidden* self-promition should be removed. (I don't consider references in a user's profile to be disclosure.) [Fully disclosed self-promotion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15787/how-do-i-mention-my-own-products-in-answers/15791#15791) is a different matter; I think *in general* that will be handled by the community votes, either up or down.

But whether commercial or non-commercial, disclosed or undisclosed: 412 out of 670 answers, that's a link to a specific website in 60% (!) of the answers.

Are these products suitable for many different cases? Are the questions duplicates of each other (in which case >3k should then vote to close, rather than answer, if you'd ask me)? Of course, one's knowledge makes one more likely to answer the questions one understands best. But would for 60% of that set of questions one's own product be the answer? Or is the set of questions not only limited to one's knowledge, but even further limited to those to which one's own products could be the answer? Like George put it [in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limit-to-self-promotion-in-answers/57508#comment-136019):

> What if every one with a commercial product to plug started searching SO for every opportunity to plug their wares?

So yes, why not define some limit to ensure that doesn't happen? That limit would probably be some random figure, like "at most 10% of one's posts", but just let's make it clear?

(**EDIT**: Added thoughts on the limit.)

Comment: I have asked several questions to which Ira provided an answer. While "here's a commercial tool" may often not the answer the asker is looking for, his answers are always on-topic and point to a product relevant to the question, so the input in itself is fine IMO. But a more clear disclosure would be desirable.

Comment: @Arjan: Fine. Let SO make the policy, either way, clear. As it is now, I don't think it's clear. I happen to disagree with you about whether you need to make your position clear, if the answer is directly relevant. Otherwise every Microsoft person will need to note they are from Microsoft when they answer a question. Mostly I'm complaining about the extra typing and the extra text to read in the answers. I would have been happy to list my email address but SO gave everybody an alias.

Comment: @Ira I think your point about Microsoft employees is not entirely valid, as they are usually involved in giving *support* on MS products rather than making product *recommendations*. Anyway, I agree that having a clear policy would be a good this; but adding the word "our" to "try SD Formatter" would make the connection very clear already.

Comment: @Pekka: I stand somewhat corrected on this. What's your position on a MS employee suggesting the use of another MS tool to help solve an OP's problem, then? (e.g., "You can use MSXSL...")

Comment: @Ira: I know you want a clear policy stated by someone in authority so you can either feel vindicated or ... I don't know, something else, but it's not a clear issue and questions can be answered in a wide spectrum of grey.  Do you have a proposed wording for that policy and are you willing to hash out the (endless) nuances of how it should be applied?  Similarly, hypothetical vague answers to unstated questions (e.g. the MSFT employee example) don't make very good policy discriminators.

Comment: @Ira they *should* mention that they are MS employees in that case IMO.

Comment: @Gnome: Not interested in vindication.  I've had this objection raised a few times in the past, but not with this much discussion. I'd like to know what to say, to avoid having this discussion again.  I suspect without such a policy, there will always be someone that objects "hey, that's a commercial product spam". (Actually I don't think the policy will stop the objections, but it will at least end the discussion quickly.)  I'd really rather be sleeping right now.

Comment: @Gnome: Regarding hashing out a specific phrasing: I'm not the powers-that-be at SO, and I'm actually not sure who is, other than the folks that started the site.  I assume they care about this topic.  I don't want to hash out something just to be nixed by a third party who wasn't involved.  I am willing participate in a hashing out

Comment: @Gnome: I have a suggestion, though. Rather than trying to phrase something repeatedly, an answer checkbox, "I represent the company that offers this product" would be easier, and provide a link to a big SO disclaimer: "this guys says he represents the company. Take what he says with a grain of salt, as he is probably biased..." all of which would be fine by me.  THen you could define SO-spam as recommending a product from your company without explicit signal, and it would be clear to everybody.

Comment: @Ira: And that's part of the impedance mismatch: we have a community site, yet you're asking for an indisputable policy to use as a measuring stick. – That suggestion is way too complicated.  If it's important to be clear about mentioning products which pay your bills and you can't do that without a complicated system (something that doesn't apply to you, just use words like "our product"), then such a person probably shouldn't be answering.

Comment: @Gnome still, there is community consensus on many issues. I'd say it's not impossible to reach. I added an answer with a suggestion for a policy.

Comment: @Pekka: Community consensus forms convention rather than authoritative policy.  I think the former is fine in this situation, combined with discussion such as on Meta.  I suggested Ira try to word it to demonstrate how hard a non-vague policy would be, and because that's a much better use of effort than repeatedly calling for someone else to do the work.

Comment: @Pekka, some more consensus at the question Michael referred to: [How do I mention my own products in answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15787?tab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: @Arjan good point, that already says it well.

Comment: @Gnome I took a shot at wording a non-vague policy below. Its essence is identical to what @Chris says in @Arjan's linked answer.

Comment: @Arjan: and what if everyone with a commercial product actually provided answers that reasonbly addressed the question? Aren't reasonable answers (tagged by votes!) the *point* of SO? Are you suggesting that only non-commercial products are useful? It strikes me that SO would become more valuable rather than less, as answers would cover a more complete spectrum of choices. *Yes, I agree the responses have to be reasonable*.

Comment: @Ira, I would surely object if everyone with whatever product or blog would come to SO to promote their thing **in 60% of the questions they post in**, apparently disregarding other questions in which they could not advertise their thing. But I assume you know your competitors, so why not suggest to use those as well in your answers? Wouldn't that make your answers better?

Comment: @Arjan: "apparantly disregarding other questions in which they could not advertise their thing..." What do you "disregard other questions"? There's 250+ examples by your own admission of places where I could not "advertise" my thing and yet I did something arguably constructive.  Regarding knowing my competitors: yes, I could supply more data; once in a while I actually do that.  Do you provide a list of all the options you know for every question?  I doubt it.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution could be to have vendors who promote their own products be given a special tag next to their name. That would take care of the disclosure problem in a simple and convenient way, as well as having the potential for people who are bothered by such posts to be able to filter out ALL self-promotional material that was posted in accordance with the rules.

Comment: sure, as long as they pay us for that privilege. Current price is one million dollars.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I'm not sure if I understand why a tag is a privilege (especially a very expensive one)?   I believe that having your posts, entirely and silently, filtered out by a noticeable portion of the user base here is far more of a negative effect than the small boost to reputation that a tag (similar to the verified tag found on many sites) would be.

Answer (score 5):

I despise spammers, but I think I'm on Team Ira (i.e., I don't think he's a spammer). He's on topic, and doesn't try to hide his association. HOWEVER, when his answers get flagged for spam, I don't automatically clear the flags. While I'm on the team, if the community wishes to declare an answer spam (six flags over an answer) it'll get deleted. While I can't see who has flagged, I've emailed one user who asked for direct mod intervention, letting them know why Ira isn't banned (not spammer, no direct action; community decides fate of answers)

Comment: Thank you for respecting the wishes of the community.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary for all his answers to be in one group or the other, which seems to be where a lot of conversations are stuck here. I check the spam flags pretty regularly, and most of his answers that've been flagged I think were good, particularly the ones on a question that specifically asked for a tool recommendation. Others completely don't answer the question, and a number of times he ends his answer with something along the lines of "the tool I just spent three paragraphs describing doesn't actually solve your problem, but it's kind of related" -- those I consider spam

Comment: So, does the policy being formulated about attribution in this thread mean anything?  Or is just, "well, if you agree with the policy its OK, otherwise just do what you wish?"

Comment: @Ira if Jeff or Joel or somebody comes up with a well defined policy on this and informs me of it I'm all in.  The community is, and should be, mostly self policing.  Mods should only intervene in extreme cases.  THAT IS POLICY.  I'm willing to go along with it.  Since there is no "**the policy**" other than this, your comment confuses.  Also, since I'm essentially on your side in a kind-of neutral way, I'm not sure where you're coming from.  Be as proactive as possible and most of this goes away.  You're 80% there.

Answer (score 4):

When those spam votes started coming in I looked at circa 5 of Ira's posts that had been flagged, found that they all contained an admission of the relationship (usually *"Our FooBaricator 2000 can..."* which is admittedly minimal), saw that several had positive comments from other participants, and decided to let it go.

The sheer volume does give me some pause, but each answer should be evaluated on it's own, and the ones I looked at were responsive at a non-trivial level.

May I suggest to Ira a more prominent disclosure?

Comment: `May I suggest to Ira a more prominent disclosure?` I'm curious to see Ira's response, as the `Our` wording is a result of suggestions in this question.

Comment: @George: Is it? I though It has been a while, but I thought I caught the leading edge of that business...I was in the middle of moving apartments then, so I didn't spend much time on Meta, but I was looking at SO in the little cracks of my days. (And to...uhm, "test" that the internet at the new place was up to speck. Yeah.)

Comment: A policy has been suggested.  It appears to have been upvoted significantly more than other suggestions. (Do I really have to repeat this again?): I've agreed to follow the policy.  It does not require a long disclosure.  To the extent the policy becomes known *and followed*, I suspect it will be a very good signal.

Comment: @Ira: Please don't get your hackles up. I was late to the party, and chose for myself to let things stand the way they were in any case. *I'd* prefer to see a more prominent disclaimer, but I'm not about to go slapping extraneous spam flags on your work.

Comment: @dmckee: Sorry if I seem a bit irritated.  I've taken rather a lot of flak from George Marian and friends, and if my previous comment seems uptight, its because George already knows I've committed to chosen policy, and I'm tired of repeating it for him.

Comment: @ira My apologies for pushing your buttons, as I hate it when someone does that to me. However, that was not my intent. I was truly interested in seeing your response, but I should have just kept it to myself and waited. That said, you need to take the blinders off and look at the bigger picture. We've already discussed that my agreement with the policy proposed here doesn't illustrate my personal opinion on the matter. I'm relatively new to SO, and as such I haven't felt comfortable flagging your posts, for example. (cont'd)

Comment: @ira That said, I'm not new to human behavior nor am I new to communities being invaded by promoters and their detrimental effect.  All of my arguments have come from that perspective. However, you want to toe line of some "policy."  That sets off all sorts of red flags for me.  I hope you understand my perspective and don't take it as some personal attack on you.

Comment: @George: Perhaps I have misassociated you with some others here.  It sounds like *you* have agreed to follow the policy that seems suggested here, which is presumably a workable compromise for all parties involved. I'm not sure what you mean "want to toe the line".  What I want is to be able to post answers that I believe are useful; they're the answers I happen to know by virtue of being buried deeply in them.   Based on the evidence I see, there are those that don't care what compromise is reached.  They are working on convincing me that providing answers that I have to SO are wasted.

Comment: ... I believe that will make SO a poorer place, even if others do not.

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes find questions on S.O. without adequate answers.   If I can code up a good solution, I do so, then I post a link to my github repo or gist, as well as a copy of the code (usually remembering to mention that the link is to my repo/gist).

The reason for the link is that stack overflow is not a good repository.   You can't include GPL license info, fork it, multiple files, etc.

IMO: Links to open source gists and github repos *in support of a relevant answer* should never be called spam.  (It's even there in the guidelines)

Comment: Erik, this question is 11 years old. A gist or repo you wrote up to help solve a particular question is NOT the subject of this question. (If anyone told you otherwise, then they are incorrect.)

Comment: I had a bunch of posts of mine, where links to gists written to solve the problem removed by @martijn-pieters.  in 100% of the cases, i wrote the lib/gist to solve the question, and provided relevant detals.   sometimes i did forget to say i wrote it, so i corrected it .   he referred to this 11 yo article as evidence that linking to a gist is wrong.  hence i responded here.

Comment: This post, and the ones referenced, are about self-promotion. If you wrote a library, then came to Stack Overflow and found questions roughly related to what your library does, then posted answers with links to your library, then that is self-promotion. If you read a question, were inspired to write up a solution in a gist, and then included it in answer, then this question does not cover that. However, gists and repos go away over time, so it's important that your answer be complete even without the gist. For example, lots of answers contain links to JSFiddle, but that site no longer exists.

Comment: If Martin pointed you to this post, then either he was confused about the origin and purpose of your repos or else he pointed you to the wrong post (maybe he meant this one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Martin has spent the last 3 years modifying all my posts, and linking here as the reason why

Comment: If you are having trouble with another user, flag one of your posts with a custom flag. Those go directly to the diamond mods. Explain the situation and they can moderate between you two. There's nothing more a regular user, like me, can do.

Comment: (Ignoring Martin is also an option, if you feel you are in the right)

Comment: i can't. he's a god mode editor and just went through all my posts and deleted references to all open source repositories and gists, even those maintained by people other than me. i will try flaggin things, thanks.  he also deleted some of my replies, many of which were the best possible answers.

Comment: OK... sounds like you need to resolve this issue with Stack Overflow then. There is more here than I or any non-mod has access to.

Comment: you were helpful anyway, i didn't know about the flag thing

Answer (score -4):

My rep at Stack Overflow is not yet that big, but ad and links to own contributions are a sensitive matter. So I try to write a suggestion.

**Idea**

Extend the answer section with a checkbox: "I'm promoting my own product/article. It may be commercial."

Checking the box has these consequences:

1. Any downvoting will be not result in -2, but -40 reps, and any upvoting will not be worth +10, but +20 reps.
2. In order to set a link on your own commercial webpage, you need a reputation of at least 500.
3. In order to vote such an answer, you also need a reputation of at least 500. (500 should be enough to understand what is going on.)

Sanction: Anyone setting a link to her/his own contribution/webpage/product and not checking the box will first be warned and then banned.

**Possible Consequences**

If you promote your own links, with the mechanism explained the stakes are much higher. You can ruin much of your rep by misguiding or misusing the community's willingness to discuss freely about solutions.

You can't come in as a "fresh company" and place some ad as you don't have the rep to poker with, and you won't find much attention. Your answer with your link might show a downvote number of "-200", which is a bright red alert lamp for everybody. It might also show +50, but then you have earned it.

Real spammers will have struggle harder to mask their activities.

It is up to the community to decide what is annoying and what is not. Like this, nobody has to judge if sth is inside the limit or not.

People who wish to solve common problems by presenting an own tool may do so, but they will act carefully, not area-wide.

Most links for own contributions would probably move to the comments in order not to provoke downvoting the answer. In comments, such links are ok to me.

Other than @Pekka, I don't suggest a policy change as I don't believe such changes have enough influence in this case.

Thanks for reading :-) Many ideas are not meant to be realized 1:1, but to trigger other ideas. So may it flow...

Comment: Adding an extra checkbox for this doesn't seem warranted.  There are probably a gazillion things we could possibly add a checkbox for, but think how ugly the UI would become!  Moreover, your rep proposal seems poorly thought out (imagine the opportunity to game things all over the place!).

Comment: Thx for reading. I fully agree about not overloading the UI with controls. - Sometimes, answering questions in SO in high traffic subjects has much of a game in it :-) It is not the main issue, but it is inherently there. - The intention is 1) to let the community decide what is annoying and 2) to set high risks for your own actions. I am curious if such a "democratic" regulation would be welcome here (let's forget about the premature pointing system and the UI).

Comment: Why +20 rep for an upvote?