# Answers advertising own application

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

[ETL Man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/518129/etl-man) has given etl-tools as his website, and as far as I can see all his answers recommend etl-tools. Is this an acceptable level of advertising, and if not, what is the best approach?

Comment: See also [Limit to self-promotion in answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limit-to-self-promotion-in-answers)

Answer (score 2):

If it was me (and I will do shortly) is "flag as spam" on some of the answers. Then the right people will see the rest of the answers and deal with it.

It would be OK if he mentioned he was affliated with the product, as mentioned in the FaQ:

> > **May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?**
> >
> > Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if they happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers