# Put on hold as off-topic

Tags: discussion, on-hold

There are three questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527912/how-to-compute-the-standard-normal-homogeinity-test-buishand-range-test-von-ne), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516157/r-zeroinfl-function-pscl-package-glm-advice-tutorial-walkthrough), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535335/abc-analysis-in-r) on Stack Overflow. But, it surprises me because, the first two has been on hold while the last one is still not. They all are asking the same question which is whether there is any package. I know the last one deserves to be closed; but the question is why are there inconsistencies among the moderators about which to close and which not to.

**Updated:** 
The latest [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574098/r-examine-interaction-term-based-on-quantiles) that is put on hold but then migrated to CV.

Comment: It was asked *2 hours ago*. Give it a bit.

Comment: It's getting there, it has three close votes. The meta effect :)

Comment: and now it's closed

Comment: not yet; still there

Comment: I edited the last one and re-opened it, @user227710. While originally it was a request for library recommendations, it didn't *have* to be.

Comment: @Shog9 : It would be really nice if you also reword the first two questions and appear on SO.

Comment: I don't really understand the problems being attacked on those well enough to try, @user227710. If you feel that you can do so, do it!

Comment: @Shog9: I have not enough reputation for that, and I know they will be closed for lack of code or example. I am now closely following this pattern and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574098/r-examine-interaction-term-based-on-quantiles) is the latest one put on hold.

Comment: I just migrated that one, since a CV user asked for it. I expect closure could have been avoided if he'd just asked how to analyze / graph the data rather than asking for a *package* to do this for him.

Comment: There is another one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813636/kendall-w-with-tie-corrections-in-stata) that is just asking the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last question is only 2 hours old. Chances are, nobody with close privileges has seen it yet and voted to close it.

If you see a question that you think should be closed, you can vote to close yourself if you have >3000 rep, and you can flag it if you have >15 rep.

Comment: Hmm.  Why aren't these questions on-topic?  They're specifically about programming --- they all ask how to ask R to do a specific kind of analysis.  How does this differ materially from "how do I use this thing from boost to do what it's supposed to do?", apart from a phrasing issue ("which function do y'all like?" versus "which function does this?")?

Comment: @tmyklebu: it turns out that particular turn of phrase can be rather problematic. For details, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/recommendation-question and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86717/defining-the-limits-of-self-promotion

Comment: @Shog9: OK, I see it now.  It's pretty clear that this would be a real problem in other software ecosystems.  I don't think R and its community work quite the same.  I guess the solution in the case of "which R package does <foo>?" is to ask on CrossValidated, where the users know more about what's up anyway, rather than SO?

Comment: Some of these questions are acceptable on Cross Validated, @tmyklebu - that said, on *both* sites you're better off if you can describe the problem you're trying to solve rather than leading with a request for a package; as in the example here, many tasks can be accomplished with standard functions.