# Concerns regarding deleted answers

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I could understand why the following posts may look like spam, however they perfectly answer the requested problems. I spent a good amount of time creating this fix and wanted to share it so that others do not have to.

- [Prevent scroll bounce for the body element, but keep it for child elements in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663576/prevent-scroll-bounce-for-the-body-element-but-keep-it-for-child-elements-in-io)
- [Disabling iOS elastic body scroll & keep native scrolling working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108599/disabling-ios-elastic-body-scroll-keep-native-scrolling-working)
- [Javascript for iOS: Elastic Scrolling without disabling all Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186611/javascript-for-ios-elastic-scrolling-without-disabling-all-scrolling)

I chose to post in multiple threads because the question has been phrased several different ways. Each thread I posted to was found by using different google search terms.

I want to repeat, I made these posts as I believe it is the best existing solution. I do not believe deleting my posts benefits the community.

Apologies if I used poor Stack Overflow etiquette. I would be happy to discuss alternative solutions, but I'd appreciate if these answers would get back out there so that others may benefit from them.

Comment: If the same answer does indeed solve all three of those questions (and it looks like it does), two of them should be closed as duplicates and maybe even merged.

Answer (score 10):

I don't see anything wrong with your post other than the fact that you posted it in four different places.  That's the only thing that feels "spammy" about it to me. You're linking to GitHub, which is fine since you're not asking people to look at ads or donate money, you're just providing a free open source project.  You also give an example of how to use your code *in your answer*, which is also good, but that could probably be expanded a little bit.

I went ahead and closed the three questions you linked to as duplicates of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8488447/1288), since it's the one with the most views. Your answer there is not deleted, so people who find the other questions will be able to follow the link to the original question where your answer is.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with your course of action. I would be happy to further extend my answer..

Comment: I'm glad you agree that concerns of spam are somewhat overblown here, Bill, given the free-as-in-beer, free-as-in-paint-your-face-blue, free-as-in-no-banner-ads nature of the offered work. It would be great, though, @JaridR.Margolin, if the answer stood on its own a little better. Keeping the code synced between your answer and the repo is a thankless task, so I don't suggest copy-pasting, but I think a more extensive usage example, or some description of your strategy  (if/when you have time to write it) -- moving it away from just being a link IOW -- would make the answer even more welcome.

Comment: As requested... http://stackoverflow.com/a/19651935/2687857

Answer (score 6):

If you're posting the same answer to several different questions something is almost certainly wrong somewhere.

The first option to consider is that the questions might be duplicates.  If they have the *exact* same answer, even if they are slightly different, it's at least a strong indication that they may be close *enough* to be duplicates.

If they *aren't* duplicates then the answers should, even if they are similar, be tailored to the questions they are answering.  There should be something to address or call out what makes the questions different that differs in the answer, even if it's just how it's explained, not what it is.

Next, there are also spam related concerns in your answer.  It would appear that you wrote up an answer, and you have a product that you want to push, and you're just going around to all of the questions that you can find and posting something to push people to your product.  That is spamming, and is not acceptable behavior.  [As per the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers):

> if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product, you're clearly here for the wrong reasons.

If you happen to be answering a question that just so happens to be able to be effectively solved using a product of yours, and you write up a quality answer to the post, tailored to that answer, that also happens to mention that product within it, then that's fine, but that's not what you were doing, you were going out of your way to find places to which you could advertise your product.

Comment: I would be happy to write more tailored answers for each question.

I am promoting the library I wrote as it is IMO the best solution to the problem.

However, after reading other comments, maybe some of these threads should be merged.

Comment: @JaridR.Margolin That would still be spam though, given that you're going around looking for places to plug your product.

Comment: If it answers the questions, why should it not be presented? How do you feel about merging some of the above threads, and allowing me to better tailor my answer. My intentions are not spam. My intentions are to present users with the best possible solution.

Comment: @JaridR.Margolin You say that, but your actions indicate otherwise.  So far your account hasn't done anything *but* advertise for your own product, and it has exhibited behavior indicating you went out of your way to find places to try to advertise, rather than simply mentioning the product on occasion when you happened to come across a question it applies to.

Comment: If it answers the questions, why should it not be presented? I stumbled on all 3 of the above threads when I was trying to find a solution for this problem... As users search for different terms, they will be brought to the different threads. The best solution should be available. You chose not to answer my question, which offered what I feel is a viable solution (merge threads and further tailor my response), and instead question my motives. Can we attempt to discuss with less finger pointing?

Comment: @JaridR.Margolin You're more than welcome to read the FAQ entry on why advertising is not allowed.  I don't see the need to reiterate it.