# Is it considered bad form to link to paid tutorial?

Tags: discussion

I've made a Pluralsight training course for users of my open source library, as a resource to help answer in detail lots of the most commonly asked questions. You do however need to be a Pluralsight subscriber to watch it which isn't free and I get a small royalty cut when people do watch it.

If someone asks a question on SO about a topic that I address in detail in the training course, is it considered OK for me to give a brief answer outlining the general approach to solving the issue at hand, and then point them to the Pluralsight course if they want a more detailed answer?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers

Comment: The community has shown little tolerance to self promotion - even when there is no money involved, so I can only imagine doing this would not be in your best interests as a [so] user.

Comment: I'd say, keep it out of your answers, but add a link to it in your profile. That's fair game. If you manage to provide great answers, your profile will get some decent attention as well.