# What are limitations on self-answered questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, self-answer

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) I see that "Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions".

But is there any limitations on the self-answered questions?
I guess they are surely must be on-topic for the site and this is not mentioned just because it is the obvious, am I correct? Is there any other limitations?

In the blog there is an entry: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

which says "never hesitate to ask and answer your own question on any Stack Exchange site".
**How official is this position?**

For example; we can consider this question and discussion in comments to it:
[Task 39 from iqtest.dk](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1872/task-39-from-iqtest-dk)
It raises two specific questions:

1. Must self-answered question be interesting for many people? If yes, then how many?
2. Must it be as narrow and specific as possible, as required from usual questions?

I see that one other specific question (about self-promotion questions) where already answered here: [Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers) , but not the mentioned above.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The limitations on self-answered questions are the same limitations we put on questions and answers that are not self-answered.

The question needs to be on-topic, of high quality (well, certainly not low quality) and as much as possible, not a duplicate of an existing question and yes - narrow and specific, just like any other question.

The answer should... answer the question, be correct, of high quality (link only answers are bad) and if it has any kind of self-promotion, should indicate so (you have already linked to the Limits for self-promotion post, so I won't repeat that).

---

In short, if you have had a question that you have found the answer to, that would make a good question on Stack Overflow, feel free to self answer it, so long as both question and answer are of the quality we expect. There are no other limitations.

Comment: **"so long as both question and answer are of the quality we expect"** - that's the key phrase in the context of [the question which spawned this meta](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1872/task-39-from-iqtest-dk). I don't believe that that question met the standard required to make it "good" on that site, but that's the subject of a different meta and beyond the scope of MSE.