# Is it OK to include my own library in my answer to my own question?

Tags: discussion, self-answer, self-promotion

I wanted to do something in a programming language once. The only way to do it back then was pretty verbose, so I created an open source library to make it much easier.

It's encouraged to answer your own questions here, but is it also OK to mention your own library in the answer? Of course I want to list several ways of achieving the task at hand (including the verbose method and some other open source libraries) in my answer. But still: it's kinda self promoting.

So: OK or not OK?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers

Comment: Isn't it a dupe, @Oded?

Comment: I think that is the other way around (posting answers to one other's questions), but basically the answer is the same @Sha.

Answer (score 6):

If you asked a question yourself to get this solved and you think your library is useful to others, yes! please post it. If it isn't a blatant advertisement, but actually contributing something to the overall knowledge base, we really appreciate your answer.

Make very explicit you are the owner of the project. That will prevent people accusing you of spamming SO. You might want to include useful code if it doesn't take too long, or highlight the interesting parts.

Answer (score 2):

"I wrote a library to solve this" is a perfectly valid thing to mention in an answer.

Just on its own, it's not a *good* answer; in fact, arguably it's [not an answer at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).  But you can certainly mention the existence of your library, and link to it, as long as you make sure to *also answer the question directly* in your answer.  This could e.g. involve explaining how your library solves the problem, and perhaps including some relevant parts of the library code, cleaned up for presentation if and as needed.

A useful rule of thumb is to ask yourself whether, if all copies of your library were to suddenly disappear from the Internet, a reasonably skilled programmer could still solve the problem based on your answer.

All this applies equally well to both self-answers and other answers.  It should, however, be noted that self-answered question are often held to a slightly higher standard by many voters.  Basically, when you're asking a question to answer it yourself, you do need to somehow convince people that the question you're asking really is important and/or interesting to people other than yourself, and that you're not just asking it to give yourself a chance to show off, soapbox or advertise your own work.  I'm not aware of any specific trick for that — you just have to be convincing, scope your question reasonably (not too narrow, not too broad), and of course pick a question that other people actually *do* want an answer for.