# Can I create a self-answered question and add my website as a reference?

Tags: support, self-answer, self-promotion

I've some interesting Q&A posts about programming in my personal blog and I would like to post these questions (and the respective answers) on Stack Overflow, because a lot of people can be helped (for real, you can't find the answers easily on the web).

I know that users are encouraged to create self-answered questions, but can I create a self-answered question that is already available at my website? And my main question: can I link my blog as a reference for the answer of the question?

Hope that I've made the question clear, but ask me if you don't get something.

Comment: Yes, that what I meant. I already did it sometimes (create a self-answered question and add my website as a reference for the answer), but some members criticized saying that I was breaking rules and that I was creating self-answered questions for self-promotion reasons. What should I do in this case?

Comment: @Peter not a dupe, this one here is about the self promotion aspect.

Comment: This is not very different then self promotion in answers in general, not related to the answer being a self answer. The answers on the faq still stand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think self-answered questions such as you describe are OK to post *as long as you are sensitive to how they are being received by the community*.

If you find they are being downvoted, or moderators are messaging you to suggest that you are stepping over the line in terms of what is OK with respect to self-promotion on that site, then you will be wise to take extra care not to be self-promoting, or to be perceived as being self-promoting.

I suspect that the first thing that you should lose from a poorly received self-answer that includes a link to your blog *is the link to your blog*.  Q&As should be standalone so doing that should not "break" your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This question helped me, too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers