# How to deal with persistent Spam-Users

Tags: discussion, spam, spam-detection

> ***See also:*** [How to deal with Spam-Users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52475/how-to-deal-with-spam-users)

I've been flagging [this guy](https://superuser.com/users/45228/zlatan24) already four times (same username, same advertised website), everytime he gets deleted, but he keeps coming back.

Should I just keep flagging him or is there a 'do *that* if that happens' procedure?

Comment: Keep flagging him, @Gnoupi loves to get a higher kill count on [Deposit](http://superuser.com/users/43131/deposit)

Comment: *"The suspension period ends on May 4 '84 at 11:02."*, holy @$@#!.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The goal of these spammers is to **spam their URL everywhere**. So we can use that against them; it is their weakness.

Just make sure you report the URL back to us, and we will add it to the blacklist.

When flagging users like this, make sure you mention "url should be blacklisted" in your mod flag comment so we know what to do!

Comment: How does blacklisting work? What if some hapless user reports a URL that is a legitimate answer because he thinks it looks like spam but is actually helpful? I'm of course assuming the moderators will verify for themselves but what if one just woke up and didn't put the effort into verifying it that he should have? Is there a way to double-check the URL blacklist to ensure that nothing good is being blocked accidentally?

Comment: @Weblog: Maybe posting a blacklisted link will only cause an automated flag on that post

Comment: And what if they don't post an URL? There's a Spam-User since Friday (flagged, don't worry ;) ) which just keeps coming, but doesn't post an URL.