# spam account/domain needs attention - target java.pakcarid.com

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts, spam, abuse

[This account (*now deleted*)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594697/lois)  is always posting the same message that links to a different documented API function each time. The dead giveaway is the Google Ads heading and large Web development services banner in addition to the consistency of every answer that contains no helpful information except a direct link to the advertisement page.

I noticed the account when the message was wrongly posted as an answer to a [C# Winforms question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074356/add-behavior-to-group-of-windows-form-controls/5087129#5087129). I flagged the answer for a moderator attention; however there seems to be no way to flag the entire account for moderator attention so I'm posting the info here.

For my justification of flagging this account see [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) in the FAQ.

**Update 1 - further investigation**
Here's a sample of the URL that was posted (from my browser history):
`http://java.pakcarid.com/Cpp.aspx?sub=640&ff=4142&topid=46&sls=25`

Here's a sample of the answer format - it's always the same: one sentence, one link, linking to a function on the java.pakcarid.com domain.

> Coordinates of the cursor relative to
>   the screen
>
> `http://java.pakcarid.com/Cpp.aspx?sub=386&ff=3064&topid=40&sls=25`

These answers are relatively useless as far as information considering they are templated and especially compared to real answers in the thread.

[**Click here and judge for yourselves by scanning Stackoverflow for java.pakcarid.com via Google search.**](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+%2Bjava.pakcarid.com&)

---

**Update 2 - Report this Adsense account to Google**

I'd encourage the community (if they feel comfortable) to visit http://java.pakcarid.com/ click the "Ads by Google" logo and report the account.  I submitted the following report to Google. Feel free to use it for your own report.

> This site creates user accounts on
>   https://stackoverflow.com/ and plants
>   templated, useless answers that link
>   to its Google adsense pages. See
>   discussion about it here within the
>   community among users and moderators
>   [spam account/domain needs attention - target java.pakcarid.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80327/)

( and provide a link back to this article of discussion)

Comment: Related, maybe duplicates: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52475/how-to-deal-with-spam-users http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66148/what-is-too-much-self-promotion-and-where-do-we-draw-the-line http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61249/usernames-as-advertising-or-spam http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59748/how-to-deal-with-persistent-spam-users (I think I just violated the self-promotion rule ;P )

Comment: I've seen that URL before, and flagged it as spam when it was being posted by another user.  Because this is a repeat offender, you can also ask to have the URL blacklisted so they won't be able to post it in the future.

Comment: Wished I had caught that URL to save it here in the comments. Did anybody else get it before the account was deleted? (I can check my browser history on my home computer this evening).

Comment: Based on my investigation of java.pakcarid.com I've flagged another answer for mod attention linked to this meta article asking for the domain to be blacklisted.  The flag was added to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481251/what-does-document-domain-document-domain-do/4084752#4084752 and linked back to this meta discussion. pakcaird seems to be linked all over the place on SO.

Comment: Yes, this was typical of an account that quietly registers, makes a few tolerable posts and then starts spamming like crazy.

Comment: Can the domain java.pakcarid.com be blacklisted based on this information? To prevent similar accounts being opened and linking to it in the future.

Comment: @John K - I'll send a recommendation to blacklist it, as it seems to be a concerted effort to plant links. Just saw your flag for it.

Comment: Would you believe Lois is back? With several more accounts? I'm quite _certain_ that domain will enjoy a network wide ban.

Comment: Wow.  I ran that query you linked and found no fewer than three `lois` accounts, each of which was spamming that URL in their answers: [lois](http://stackoverflow.com/users/457945/lois), [lois](http://stackoverflow.com/users/467838/lois), and [lois](http://stackoverflow.com/users/552015/lois).  I've flagged all of them.

Comment: @Brad Larson - You are my hero.

Comment: Somehow I do believe it! :) I hope we can blacklist Lois' domain so they can create another and do the same.  I think Lois has unknowingly become my arch nemesis and I will fight until the day I die. Move over Bruce Willis in Unbreakable.

Comment: I posted **Update 2** in case anybody wants to report the Adsense account to Google.

Comment: @John K: Welcome to the league of Spam-Hunters. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We blacklisted this URL so it can't be added any more.

Any time you see a URL repeated more than at least ~3 times, let a moderator know and they can esclalate it to us for blacklisting.

Comment: Why can not the system detech URL with prefixes that are used more the a few time, so they can be checked out.  (Or maybe stop low rep users posting any URL that points to a page with google adverts on it.)

Comment: @Ian Ringrose: Your last suggestion would require a http-round-trip to that page inlcuding parsing of it.

Comment: @Bobby, true, but only when pages on web sites with more the n links to them would be worth checking and once the web site has been recorded as OK, there would not be a need to check every link to it.

Comment: @Ian Ringrose: That would need a white-list...and maintaining those can be expensive with not much gain. But I agree on the first part of your suggestion, a script pretty similar to the vote-fraud-mechanism could check for such things on a regular basis.

Answer (score 4):

Just flag one post for `Moderator Attention` and add something like `I think this is a Spam-User, can you please have a deeper look and maybe delete the whole user? Thanks.`. And, tada, one Spammer less on SE.

**Edit:** You can always flag question/answers/users even if you're unsure what to do with them, or if you are unsure if they've really violated a rule. A mod will look at it and decide what to do. Alternately, you can use the chat and post the specific information there.

**Edit2:** Also, if you want to go an extra mile, you can get [Web of Trust](http://www.mywot.com/), which is basically a community-driven rating system for websites, and flag 'em there for spam. But be careful if it is a subdomain of a 'good' web-hoster, because the rating will be shared with it's parent.

Comment: Thanks. I did so and linked to this question so the mod can have more info.

Comment: Chat's a great idea for immediate interaction. Wish I had thought of that. Thanks again.

Comment: @John K - There's usually at least one SO mod and one SO employee in "The Tavern" on chat.meta.stackoverflow.com Just mention one of us by @name.