# Spam accounts - how to handle?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, spam

There are accounts that present spam in their user profile and have no single post.

Two examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/842515/www-airmaxjordanfusion-com
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/750706/www-tattoos-nu?tab=stats

Obviously their only goal by creating the accounts was to gain Google rank - quick test proved their profile is indexed.

So, should I report them all here? (Can't flag as they have no post)

Or is there any better mechanism?

Some more if you want to hunt..

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/653107/www-21geba-com
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/777651/www-innovacall-com
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/874626/www-fuuby-net
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/960986/www-tuchateo-com
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/837645/www-karapyz-com

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74440/what-should-community-mods-do-with-spammers. Posting here might well be the best thing to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is spam in the "about me" field a reason to worry?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105218/is-spam-in-the-about-me-field-a-reason-to-worry)

Comment: @lunboks thanks, completely forgot about this one! However, see many spam accounts there that were never nuked..

Comment: There are a few more obvious ones if you search for `www` on [the users page](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all).

Answer (score 2):

There have previously been topics on meta about how to handle spam users, you might want to read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52475/how-to-deal-with-spam-users) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59748/how-to-deal-with-persistent-spam-users).

With them having no posts at this very moment it's impossible to actually flag anything, but at the same time their spam isn't quite as effective. Based on a bit more looking around on meta I would suggest adding the accounts to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105218/is-spam-in-the-about-me-field-a-reason-to-worry) question potentially as it already contains a rather big list of other spam accounts and keeps everything in one clear place for the moderators / staff.

Comment: No, I can't flag them as we don't have "flag profile" option (yet) - if you can find existing question with list such as I've made it would fit though, I couldn't find.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ah, true - i've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks.. flagging accounts already [suggested and declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users)

Comment: @ShadowWizard That answer mentions emailing `team@stackoverflow.com`, might be worth a go?

Comment: Maybe, better someone from the team come over and say what they prefer. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard found another meta article (see the link in the answer) which already has a huge list of spam accounts + has jeff answering.

Comment: Oops didn't see lunboks' comment!

Comment: Yeah, that was what I was looking for but looks like it either lost the moderators attention, or they decided not to delete such accounts after all.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's actually possible to flag such profile, it's just not convenient. You can always flag your own post with "other" and leave a link to the profile URL and explain.

Comment: @HoLyVieR too confusing IMO - better post it here, don't you agree? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's not that bad, I've done it once and there wasn't a problem as far as I know.