# Will facebook.stackoverflow have its own moderators to clean up the likely flood of low quality & duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, mini-site, facebook.stackoverflow

Previously, the Facebook tag on Stack Overflow has been for programming related questions.

In contrast, the old Facebook developer forum is/was filled with tons of junk and duplicates and non-programming questions.

How will this work now that their old forums are being marked read-only at the end of the month?  Will they have their own moderators to clean up the likely flood of low quality & duplicate questions speeding toward Stack Overflow like a swarm of angry bees?

Comment: Who's keeping your from doing your civic duty and use your flags appropriately?

Comment: I am - already almost out of flags for the day. But not enough people flagging to close questions.  Most of the questions posted today have nothing to do with programming.

Comment: The volume of flags coming from those tags has not increased at all (or rather, hardly) since the announcement. I do expect more once the forums go read only, but no more than I'd expect from any other popular tag. I see the concern, but it's not one that has to be addressed preemptively. Trust me, if it becomes problematic, you'll see me screaming about it.

Comment: @Tim Post: I think the problem is that there appears to be few experienced users who are active in those tags, so the lack of flags may just as well be explained by the lack of people watching those tags who know how to flag appropriately.

Comment: Hammar is correct.  Stuff that should be flagged is not getting flagged or getting enough close votes.  Has always been a problem with Facebook questions and will only get worse.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Facebook Stack Overflow has **exactly the same** rules as Stack Overflow.

Anything that's asked on Facebook shows up on Stack Overflow, and is subject to the same standards.

---

To address the edit, no.  All users are shared between Stack Overflow and Facebook; there's no distinction between moderators on one site or the other (since they really are the same "site" just different views).

If the moderator load increases, we'll do what we have done in the past and [elect additional moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56396/summer-2010-moderator-appointments).

Comment: Wow.  A huge heap of low quality, duplicates will be headed soon to Stack Overflow then. And I say this as the #4 user on that site: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

Comment: @OffBySome - there are lots of automated quality checks on Stack Overflow (and thus Facebook Stack Overflow).  We've rejected over 800 questions in the last day, for example.  I'm not concerned, but we are keeping an eye on it (we're always watching quality).

Comment: People on Facebook developer forums are just used to flooding that place with spam (check out my new app!) and using it for support (why haven't i got paid from FB credits?), that it will take them a while to get used to.

Comment: @Kevin, I thought you guys were [heading away from the "add more mods" approach](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101431/should-stack-overflow-moderators-have-a-standard-of-duty)?

Comment: @Popular Demand - that post has to deal with moderators who don't moderate, giving the impression that there are more "effective moderators" than there are.  It's not really related.

Comment: @OffBySome don't worry. The SO community is big enough to deal with those.

Comment: @offby no, [that already happened a long time ago](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/hello-stack-overflow.html) .. it's very old news. The fallout from that is [still ongoing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100529/help-us-clean-up-the-android-tag) and IMHO far worse.

Comment: @Jeff Glad down votes are free.

Answer (score 5):

No. Facebook.StackOverflow.com is StackOverflow.com but only Facebook tags are shown. When you post question on Facebook.StackOverflow.com, you post will be shown on both Facebook.StackOverflow.com and StackOverflow.com, too

Answer (score 5):

If you see any questions about *using* Facebook then flag those for a moderator to migrate to Web Applications - assuming the question meets Jeff's ["don't migrate rubbish"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91411/why-was-this-question-closed-as-off-topic-without-being-migrated/91446#91446) rule. However, "spam (check out my new app!)" and "support (why haven't i got paid from FB credits?)" questions are off topic there too.

If one of the Web Applications moderators is around the Stack Overflow moderators can check we want it, but at the end of the day we can always close (probably as a duplicate) on Web Applications.

People might get the message and start posting directly there in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

I think it would probably be a good idea to watch the Facebook tags a bit more closely in the next few days to help establish the standard we expect on Stack Overflow.

Since visitors to the new site will only see the Facebook-related questions, it's especially bad if many of the posts there have quality issues, and people start learning eachother's bad behavior.

Once the initial flood of new users has started to settle, I expect things to return to normal, but there's a lot of bad posts coming in there right now.