# Facebook.SO for all developer support, not just programming?

Tags: discussion, mini-site, facebook.stackoverflow

The [FB blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/545/) says they're moving their developer community to facebook.SO now. However a number of reasonable Facebook developer questions have started appearing e.g.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185810/credits-special-incentives-closed
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183794/troubles-with-facebook-account-verification-for-developer

which are getting closed because they're not programming related. So facebook.SO isn't a complete replacement as there's no longer a place to ask questions like this.

So how can we fix this? Either we allow non-programming Facebook questions or we push them back to Facebook's own forums (that they're closing) somehow - where?

(Maybe this is covered by [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103766/will-facebook-stackoverflow-have-its-own-moderators-to-clean-up-the-likely-flood) but I think some action / clarification is needed at both ends.)

Comment: This is going to be **major** problem once their forum becomes read only. As a passive Facebook Forum reader, I can assure you that forum gets filled with crap.

Comment: See my answer here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103766/will-facebook-stackoverflow-have-its-own-moderators-to-clean-up-the-likely-flood/103769#103769 - **if it's suitable** flag for migration to Web Applications. Unfortunately the two questions you link to wouldn't be suitable.

Comment: [God.  Damnit.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265302/why-can-i-not-put-an-apostrophe-i-my-name-if-its-on-my-birth-certificate#question) (10k+)

Answer (score 19):

On their [support page](https://developers.facebook.com/support/), they list three options: 1) Q&A (Stack Overflow), 2) Bugs, and 3) Community.  It is my interpretation of the Stack Overflow [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/) that Facebook.StackOverflow is just to be a filtered view, meaning the same strict guidelines apply (ie programming questions only).  I think that blog post on Facebook's site just continues to show they don't really embrace or understand the nature of Stack Overflow.

A lot of the off-topic Facebook questions getting asked really should be logged as bugs (option 2) or discussed on their community link as they aren't programming related.  I will be voting to close, voting down, and flagging non-programming Facebook questions until I get banned.

Comment: Facebook developers need a Q&A site for non-programming topics such as Facebook platform policy.  Not discussion/community, but real answers with upvotes.  It would be better to have a separate Stack Exchange site for Facebook developers so it would be inclusive of the broader scope of questions that need answers (and got answers on the soon to be read-only Facebook developer forums)

Answer (score 7):

According to [Alex Miller's blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/), [Facebook.SO](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com) represents the *subset* of Stack Overflow questions related to Facebook. Consequently, **as long as Facebook questions are visible to the rest of Stack Overflow, they need to adhere to the same rules.**

For what it's worth, [Facebook has told developers that there are now three separate locations for questions, bugs, and discussions](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/545/):

> With [the move to Stack Overflow], **we decided to make our Developer
> Forum “read-only” after September 1 in order to better support you on
> Stack Overflow.** A banner has been placed at the top of the Forum
> encouraging you to **post all new questions on Stack Overflow.**
>
> If you’d like to continue participating in the developer community,
> join us in the Facebook Developers Group, where the Developer
> Relations team is going to be hanging out.
>
> **Moving forward, Stack Overflow is where you’ll go to have your
> Facebook Platform questions answered; Bugs is where you go to report
> an issue with a legitimate repro, and you should participate in the
> Group to discuss, chat, and talk with us directly.**

Emphasis is mine.

I think that it is Facebook's responsibility to clarify that *"Facebook Platform questions" must be programming-related.* It's worth noting that **once the developer forum becomes read-only on *September 1*, the current flood of non-programming questions is probably going to get *much* worse** unless Facebook manages the transition carefully.